# X11 send notification to all users on all DISPLAY's

Tags: x11, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show a notification across all running X displays](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/show-a-notification-across-all-running-x-displays)

As root, I am trying to execute a command on remote servers that pops-up a message window to users; the question is, without su - user (because it takes too much time for many users), how can the correct DISPLAY value for any user be obtained?

Comment: have you tried using `wall` for the popup?

Answer (score 1):

Short: there is not the solution(TM) for what you want.

However, with sufficient knowledge about your setup it may be possible to develop a solution that works for you. I had the same problem once.

The reason why it's so difficult is that the Xserver is precicely not tied to a user. You can confirm that on any major Linux distribution by loging in to the desktop-environment of your choice, opening a terminal and typing in `ps faux`. It will show your display manager, with (at least) two child processes: a xserver and the parent process for all processes belonging to your user session. Note that the xserver is started as user root and **NOT** as the user your session belongs to.

What I did/do to match a certain xserver with a username I do a majority vote: I look at each user process and check to which xserver it is connected. From that knowledge I create a list which tells me for each user the ammount of processes that are connected to a specific xserver. An illustration of this table could look like this:

```
      |xserver :1| xserver :2 | xserver :3 | xserver :4
-------------------------------------------------------------
alice |    17    |      0     |      0     |       0
bob   |     0    |      0     |     14     |       0
eve   |     0    |     34     |      1     |       0
foo   |     1    |      1     |      1     |       8
```

With this table I perform a simple majority vote which yields the mapping:

- User alice is using, i.e. sitting in front, of xserver :1
- User bob is using xserver :3
- User eve is using xserver :2
- User foo is using xserver :4

This majority vote does not necessarily yield correct mappings however, for all my intents and purposes it's sufficient.

That's all you need. Now you can

```
DISPLAY=<ip.to.xserver>:1 xmessage -buttons yes,no,maybe -nearmouse "Do you want to go on a date with me?"
```

ask alice for a date.

The magic is the DISPLAY environmental variable which xapplications use to find out which xserver they should connect to. Most xapplications also accept the option `-display`. See the man page on `xmessage` and `X`.

Of course there are (so) many other ways to replace my majority vote with. Which is the best suited for you, you need to find out yourself ...