# Selecting icon for tray notifications from Bash scripts (KDE)

Tags: scripting, notifications, kde4

Q: How to make Qt KDE tray notification from Bash script ?

A: [@SO: Activating KDE 4 notifications from bash scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379804/activating-kde-4-notifications-from-bash-scripts)

Q: How to make notifications from scripts running as root ?

A: [@Unix.SE: Show a notification across all running X displays](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2883/9689)

**Q1:** Ok... I see `kdialog` and `notify-send` send tray notification. Am I right only `notify-send -i` allows to setup notification icon?

**Q2:** In [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522152/544721) there is `notify-send -i 'dialog-information'` icon -> what are other icons available by default ?

Q3: Will it work with other window managers ?

Answer (score 1):

`notify-send --icon=/path/to/XX.png` will only set the icon displayed in the dialog,

But for the tray icon, you need to refer to your KDE plasma theme, which is `theme_dir/icons/notification.svgz`

To find all your kde plasma themes installed, check out these two locations,

`/usr/share/kde4/apps/desktoptheme/` (system location)

And `~/.kde4/share/apps/desktoptheme/`

Comment: Could you improve your answer to make it useful for others ? Could you provide an example how to find *KDE plasma theme* to check pictures available there. Is there any standard which should be provided by all themes (like "notification") ?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki yeah, that's a standard

Comment: By *"standard"* I meant: What icons have to be provided by standard? I assume there must be some minimum set required.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [alltray](https://linux.die.net/man/1/alltray); maybe it's your solution.

From its website:

> **Description**
>
> With AllTray you can dock any application with no native tray icon (like Evolution, Thunderbird, Terminals) into the system tray. A high-light feature is that a click on the "close" button will minimize back to system tray. It works well with Gnome, KDE, XFCE 4*, Fluxbox* and WindowMaker*. Xmms is supported in particular.
>
> **Options**
>
> These programs follow the usual GNU command line syntax, with long
> options starting with two dashes ('-'). A summary of options is
> included below.
>
> -h --help | Show summary of options.
>
> -v --version | Show version of program.
>
> -d --debug | Show debug messages.
>
> -s --show | Do not hide window after start.
>
> -i --icon | Use a PNG image as an icon.
>
> -l --large_icons | allow large icons (> 24x24).
>
> -st --sticky | visible on all workspaces.
>
> -x --borderless | Remove windows decorations border, title, frame... from parent.
>
> -m --menu | Add entry "menu text:command" to popdown menu.
>
> -t --title | Show title change for  seconds. Probably most usefull for xmms.
>
> -g --geometry | initial position. see man X.

**Installation (command in a terminal)**

***- in Ubuntu:***

```
sudo apt-get install alltray
```

***- in Fedora:***

```
sudo dnf install alltray
```

Cheers