# sudo crontab notify-send doesn't work

Tags: bash, scripting, cron, environment-variables, libnotify

I have read similar posts [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289292/notify-send-from-root-cron), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298608/notify-send-doesnt-work-from-crontab) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519673/cron-with-notify-send) that mentioned some environment variables `DISPLAY` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. Setting them at the top of my user crontab enabled notify-send to work in my user crontab. However, the exact same crontab does not work if set in the `sudo crontab -e`, why not? And how can I make it work?

**test.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash
env > $1
notify-send "I want to see this"
```

**crontab -e**

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH="/usr/bin:/home/ripytide/scripts/"
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
DISPLAY=:0                                                                     
* * * * * test.sh /home/ripytide/crontab.env
```

**sudo crontab -e**

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH="/usr/bin:/home/ripytide/scripts/"
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
DISPLAY=:0                                                                     
* * * * * test.sh /home/ripytide/sudocrontab.env
```

**crontab.env**

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/home/ripytide
LOGNAME=ripytide
_=/usr/bin/env
HOME=/home/ripytide
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
USER=ripytide
DISPLAY=:0
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/bin:/home/ripytide/scripts/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

**sudocrontab.env**

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/root
LOGNAME=root
_=/usr/bin/env
HOME=/root
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
USER=root
DISPLAY=:0
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/bin:/home/ripytide/scripts/
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski That sounds promising, I assume I need to set the USER variable to my user "ripytide", after doing that it does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D-Bus checks whether UIDs of the calling process and the session daemon are the same. Your script needs to run `notify-send` as the target user. If you insist to run the script as root then in the script you need `sudo -u user notify-send …`.

Keep in mind `sudo` sanitizes the environment, so `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` from the environment of the script will not get to the environment of `notify-send` (`/etc/sudoers` and the security policy may allow `sudo` to keep the variable but in your case this probably won't happen by default).

You may try to change the settings, I won't elaborate. There is also `sudo -E` (see `man 8 sudo`). The least intrusive method is to request `sudo` to set the variable on demand:

```
sudo -u user DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" \
   notify-send "I want to see this"
```

When the shell processing the script expands `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, the command becomes:

```
sudo -u user DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus \
   notify-send "I want to see this"
```

and this form can be as well used directly, so it's up to you.

In general things may be configured not to allow `sudo` to set the variable even this way. In the worst case the following should work:

```
sudo -u user sh -c '
   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send "I want to see this"
'
```