# How to communicate with user from a root process

Tags: linux-mint, cron, root, clamav

I have a process that runs as root, from `cron.daily`, and may need to send results to a logged-in user.

Is there anything like an X version of `wall` or `write`? I am trying to avoid `mail` because it may be too involved for the user.

**Details**

I am setting up a Linux Mint Cinnamon laptop for a non-technical user, coming from a Windows 7 background. Anti-virus has been specifically requested.

This script is in cron.daily

```
#!/bin/bash
# ClamAV antivirus maintenance.
LOGFILE=/var/log/av-results.txt

# Update the signature database. Populates the file /var/lib/clamav/daily.cvd
systemctl stop clamav-freshclam
freshclam
systemctl start clamav-freshclam

# Run a scan
clamscan --infected --recursive --log=$LOGFILE /home
if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]
then
    wall "Virus(es) found. Call support"
fi
chmod 666 $LOGFILE
```

but the `wall` does not work, because the user is using Cinnamon not `terminal`.

`ClamTK` (the GUI version of `ClamAV`) has been ruled-out because I cannot get it to work.

Comment: There's an example on how to implement this at Archlinux' wiki: wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ClamAV#OnAccessScan . Don't follow it literally, the part that interests you is only the contents of `/etc/clamav/detected.sh` (though following entirely this documentation gets on-demand settings to make it behave as on Windows: realtime detection (and probably slowdown)).

Comment: @A.B And the author of that script apparently also posted (a variation of?) it on this site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307097/315749 :-)

Comment: These are a great help - but why aren't they answers?

Comment: @Peterbill To me, because, when two questions have the same set of answers, they are duplicates (and there is no point in duplicating the answers too). But I've never used Cinnamon and I can't know if the solutions proposed in the linked Q/A worked for you.