# Notify-send to login screen in Debian 11

Tags: debian, gnome, notify-send

I used [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344377) to send a message which is triggered by udev to the login screen. Which was working on Debian 10 with Gnome.

On Debian 11 this is not working anymore. The user Debian-gdm which owns the login screen has no directory /run/user/$id/dbus-session. I don't know why. I have searched but didn't found an answer what changed to Debian 11.

Do someone know the reason for this? Or has someone an advice for my task to send an notification to the login screen as another user.

Btw. if a process owned by Debian-gdm sends a notification it will displayed on login screen

Comment: What about one of the other answers, such as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/487977/100397)?

Comment: "pgrep 'gnome-session' -u Debian-gdm" has no output. Debian-gdm has no dbus!??? I do not understand what is in Debian11 different to Debian10

Comment: You will have to look for the DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in the /proc/$pid/environ of the `gnome-shell’ running under GDM.  Some of the other answers to your link provide good answers.

Comment: My setup is working in Debian 10. In Debian 11 there is no /proc/$pid/environ of 'gnome-shell' ! As i mentioned I don't understand what changed to Debian 11.