# Anacron job complains "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display"

Tags: x11, cron, scripting, gtk

I'm trying to make a simple weekly Anacron job that backs up my computer if I click yes on the dialog. The script I wrote works fine if run manually, but when Anacron runs it, nothing happens and I see `Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display` in the logs. Apparently the script is run at a stage where graphical operations cannot be run. Is there any way to get this dialog to open from an Anacron job?

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Backs up the local filesystem on the external HDD

sleep 60

DISPLAY=:0.0

zenity --question --text "Do you want to backup? Be sure to turn on the HDD."
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then exit 1
fi

*Do backup stuff here*
```

Error:

```
(zenity:2351): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/backup-on-external exited with return code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably just running without the `$DISPLAY` environment variable. If you `echo $DISPLAY` in your shell you can see what its value is (most likely `:0.0`), and then you can specify that in the crontab file:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 dialog ...
```

Comment: And the reason why it's running with no `DISPLAY` is that (ana)cron jobs are supposed to be able to run even if nobody is logged in. Relying on someone being logged in is not a good idea for something that should be automatic like a backup script (a better design would be to perform the backup if the right media is in place, and rely on the usual failure notification (through e-mail) to alert the user if the right media was not in place and the backup could not be made).

Comment: I added the DISPLAY=:0.0 line at the beginning but still got the same error. And :0.0 is the correct value for my system.

Comment: @Cory: You may also need `XAUTHORITY` as well. The default, used if the variable is unset, is `~/.Xauthority`. Some systems (e.g. Ubuntu) use a different file, and it can be a little hard to find out. If that's the issue, see http://superuser.com/questions/190801/linux-wmctrl-cannot-open-display-when-session-initiated-via-sshscreen/190878#190878 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/as-root-can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop/1600#1600 .

Comment: This did not work for me, but putting --display=:0.0 as an argument to Zenity worked

Answer (score 1):

My situation was a little different, I needed to run a GUI app from cron that had root permissions. The following lines in the shell script fixed this issue for me:

```
export DISPLAY=:0,0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/{logged in user}/.Xauthority
```

Of course I'm not really supposed to be doing this as per [this article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Running_GUI_applications_as_root#Circumvent_running_graphical_applications_as_root), but I am still yet to find a better workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should use user's crontab instead of system-wide.

Try crontab -e (opens user's crontab in $EDITOR) or echo 'your crontab line here' | crontab -

Comment: Also, instead of 'if blah-bla-bla', you can use something like: zenity --question --text "Do you want to backup? Be sure to turn on the HDD." || exit 1

Comment: This thread is about anacron, not cron ... so I think the anacron way of defining a user-specific setup should be used.

Comment: Warning : `echo 'your crontab line here' | crontab -` will *replace* all your crontab jobs with just this line. Use `{ crontab -l | grep -v "somekeyword" ; echo "my new crontab line # somekeyword" } | crontab` to add/update one line while not causing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

works for me with DISPLAY=:0.0 but I have just one user on the system so I specify that user in /etc/crontab

Answer (score 0):

You can define a user-specific anacrontab:

```
sudo anacron -t ${HOME}/.anacron/anacrontab -S ${HOME}/.anacron/spool
```

`-t` = Use specified anacrontab, rather than the default

`-S` = Use  the  specified spooldir to store timestamps in, this option is required for users who wish to run anacron themselves.

Add the command in your `~/.profile` to execute when you login.

Allow to execute 'sudo anacron' without password by adding the following line to '/etc/sudoers':

```
user    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/anacron
```

(Replace 'user' with your username)

Like that the `$DISPLAY` and the `$XAUTHORITY` of the user should be set.