# "DISPLAY=:0 sudo -u some_user zenity ..." Wayland equivalent

Tags: scripting, wayland

I have a few scripts that need to be started as root and from cron, and need basic user interaction with `zenity`. To start `zenity` on user screen, I was used to this form of command:

```
DIPLAY=:0 sudo -u some_user zenity ...
```

But **if the user is running a** `Wayland` **session**:

- `who` now shows `/dev/tty2` instead of `:0`
- the above command **does not work** (regardless `:0` or `/dev/tty2` as `DISPLAY` value), and returns `Error: Can't open display: /dev/tty2`

Do you know the "Wayland way" to achieve a similar goal? (Although I am less interested, a MIR equivalent would be an interesting bonus...)

Again, to be clearer, **my question is about** `Wayland` **user session**: I have no problem when user session is running under `Xorg`. If you still think my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80310/how-to-display-a-zenity-gui-dialog-to-the-user-after-a-root-cron-task-has-comp), please explain why.

Comment: `sudo` may very well clear your environment.

Comment: @roaima This question does not speak about Wayland.

Comment: True, but it does explain how to handle `zenity` under `cron`. FWIW after your clarification I've now voted to reopen so we'll see what happens.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for the interesting link. But if I understand well this bug report, it is about "from user Wayland session, run GUI as root", which is different from "from root cron/TTY session, run GUI as current Wayland user". The program would run as the same user as the Wayland session: it is not stated that is is not possible.

Comment: It seems I was wrong in my tests, because even if `who` reports `/dev/tty2` instead of the usual `:0`, the command works from TTY using `:0` (which is indeed the `DISPLAY` value you can get from inside the Wayland session): `DISPLAY=:0 sudo -u user some_command`. This question is solved, sorry for the noise.

Comment: Oh, ok I misunderstood the q then... no problem