# How can I use cron to display messages on the screen via notify-send

Tags: cron, notifications

I am toying around with `notify-send` and `cron` (on an Arch machine) and I can't figure out a way to combine them:

I tried the solution given [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=120501) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/111771/using-either-notify-send-or-zenity-in-cron), but neither worked. How can I use them?

**EDIT:**
I have set the DISPLAY in the crontab and it still didn't work. I tried the same in Ubuntu and there things are working fine. Here is my cron line:

```
*/1 * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/notify-send "hellp" || echo "er" > .er
```

Comment: In what way did they not work? Did you remember to set `DISPLAY`?

Comment: What are the error messages (they'll be mailed to you by local email, make sure you have an MTA installed and check `/var/mail/yotam` or `/var/spool/mail/yotam`)? You may need to set `XAUTHORITY` in addition to `DISPLAY`, see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/ssh-display-variable/10126#10126).

Comment: Does an "Authentication failure" message appear in `/var/log/cron`? If it appears, see if you have an `/etc/pam.d/crond` file on Ubuntu. If you have, steal it, otherwise see the [cron job not running because of pam?](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/448620-cron-job-not-running-because-pam.html) thread in the openSUSE forum.

Answer (score 4):

About the only thing that I can suggest is to create a named pipe and have cron write to the pipe and have a little script started by the session manager that reads from the pipe and calls notify-send:

```
while read line < /tmp/.cron2notify.s  # pipe name in /tmp
do notify-send "Cron message" "$line"
done
```

Then in the crontab, have the program write to `/tmp/.cron2notify.s`.

Haven't tested this, but should give you a starting point to work from.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `notify-send` relies on on [`D-Bus`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) on most systems, and the most common method of contacting dbus is via the `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable.  However hard-coding this in `crontab` is probably not very workable since the bus address changes every time you start a new instance of dbus which usually happens whenever you log in or reboot.  Arcege's [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20346/how-can-i-use-cron-to-display-messages-on-the-screen-via-notify-send/20348#20348) sounds like a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use Arcege's answer, but could not make it work: the while loop terminates after the first line is written to the named pipe. What worked for me was having a similar script with an infinite loop, in which I trap signals sent from cron and then call notify-send. The following is the program "notify-forward":

```
#! /bin/bash
function coffee () {
   notify-send "foo" "bar"
}
function lunch () {
   notify-send "bar" "foo" 
}
while true; do
  sleep 10
  trap coffee SIGUSR1
  trap lunch SIGUSR2
done
```

and my crontab looks like

```
55 09,13 * * * pkill -USR1 forward-notify
55 11 * * * pkill -USR2 forward-notify
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: You could wrestle with all of what you guys are doing or just use the xmessage option:

```
    MSSG="/tmp/mssg-file-${RANDOM}" 
    echo -e " MESSAGE \n ==========\n Done with task, YEY. " > ${MSSG}
    xmessage -center -file ${MSSG} -display :0.0 
    [[ -s ${MSSG} ]] && rm -f ${MSSG}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend using a wrapper script.  To emulate cron calling notify-send, I sshed into my own system with "ssh localhost".  Calling '/usr/bin/notify-send "foo"' Didn't work, and I had no luck when adding DISPLAY=:0.0 to the line.  Here is what did work:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/`pgrep -u username cinnamon|head -1`/environ | sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//')" /usr/bin/notify-send "foo"
```

That is VERY messy, to say the least.  This is cleaner.

```
#! /bin/bash

DBUS=$(pgrep -ou $1 cinnamon)
DBUS="$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$DBUS/environ | sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//')"

DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="$DBUS" /usr/bin/notify-send $2
```

And in cron:

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/notify.sh user "help"
```

Please note that the "cinnamon" bit is there because that the window manager I use.  You will likely have to replace it with nautilus, or whatever else you have as a window manager.  I also have a user specified as the first argument, because it makes it more modular later, if you want this to work regardless of who is logged in.

Comment: Worked flawlessly :) Thank you very much!