# Using notify-send with cron

Tags: shell, scripting, cron, libnotify

I am using Arch Linux with KDE/Awesome WM. I am trying to get 
`notify-send` to work with `cron`.

I have tried setting `DISPLAY`/`XAUTHORITY` variables, and running `notify-send` with "sudo -u", all without result.

I am able to call notify-send interactively from the session and get notifications.

FWIW, the cron job is running fine which I verified by echoing stuff to a temporary file. It is just the "notify-send" that fails to work.

Code:

```
[matrix@morpheus ~]$ crontab -l
* * * * *  /home/matrix/scripts/notify.sh

[matrix@morpheus ~]$ cat /home/matrix/scripts/notify.sh
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/matrix/.Xauthority
echo "testing cron" >/tmp/crontest
sudo -u matrix /usr/bin/notify-send "hello"
echo "now tested notify-send" >>/tmp/crontest

[matrix@morpheus ~]$ cat /tmp/crontest
testing cron
now tested notify-send

[matrix@morpheus ~]$
```

As you can see the echo before & after notify-send worked.
Also I have tried setting `DISPLAY=:0.0`

UPDATE:
I searched a bit more and [found that DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20346/how-can-i-use-cron-to-display-messages-on-the-screen-via-notify-send?rq=1) needs to be set. And after hardcoding this using the value I got from my interactive session, the tiny little "hello" message started popping up on the screen every minute!

But the catch is this variable is not permanent per that post, so I'll have try the the named pipe solution suggested there.

```
[matrix@morpheus ~]$ cat scripts/notify.sh
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/matrix/.Xauthority
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-BouFPQKgqg,guid=64b483d7678f2196e780849752e67d3c
echo "testing cron" >/tmp/crontest
/usr/bin/notify-send "hello"
echo "now tested notify-send" >>/tmp/crontest
```

Since `cron` doesn't seem to support notify-send (at least not directly) is there some other notification system that is more `cron` friendly that I can use?

Comment: This should work as far as I can see. Why don't you add a `&>>/tmp/crontest` to the notify send line and see if `notify-send` gives any error messages.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try my solution? It seems much simpler and worked perfectly on my Debian. I'm asking just to know if it Debian specific or not

Comment: @terdon I tried your solution (just a quick test) and it seems to work on my Debian system. I'd like to know if it's generally applicable since it is indeed simpler.

Comment: @Marco I'm on LMDE (essentially Debian testing) and using Cinnamon as DE. Can't tell you if it works beyond those.

Comment: @Marco & terdon: Ubuntu guys are able to do so: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1727148

Comment: DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is definitely not required on Debian, you can do `unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and `notify-send` still works. The arch configuration must somehow be different.

Comment: @Graeme Not here. `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS= notify-send Foo Bar` doesn't display a notification.

Comment: @Marco Hmm, same with me. This is not the same as unset though. You can also use `unset $(env | sed '/^PATH=/d; s/=.*//')` to clear everything except path. If you then set DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY, you should see that these are the only ones required. Although it seems that DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS must be valid if it exists.

Comment: In my case without DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS set I had Unity style OSD notification from crontab. I'm using gnome-shell so this was irritating because my default notifications was displayed in different style then those from crontab. Now is working!

Comment: What about simply `dbus-launch notify-send "message"`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable. By default cron does
not have access to the variable. To remedy this put the following script
somewhere and call it when the user logs in, for example using *awesome* and
the `run_once` function mentioned on the wiki. Any method will do, since it
does not harm if the function is called more often than required.

```
#!/bin/sh

touch $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
chmod 600 $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
env | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
echo 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' >> $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus

exit 0
```

This creates a file containing the required Dbus evironment variable. Then in
the script called by cron you import the variable by sourcing the script:

```
if [ -r "$HOME/.dbus/Xdbus" ]; then
  . "$HOME/.dbus/Xdbus"
fi
```

Here is [an answer that uses the same
mechanism.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84438/12779)

Comment: Glad to see that I was almost near to the solution. Thanks Marco, that is neat!

Comment: Great, I reused your answer and added some more detailed instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/a/537721/34298

Comment: Wouldn't this be a security risk? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71019/is-revealing-your-dbus-session-bus-address-a-vulnerability

Comment: @Gilles How could you do this in one line like you [mentioned in chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18187131#18187131)

Comment: I have tried so many other answers not including DBUS on ubuntu 15.10 and nothing worked. That one is simple and works flawlessly.

Comment: Suggestion: If using bash, you could `declare -p DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` instead of that `env | grep`. With standard sh, `env -i DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"` should work. These both avoid the possibility of getting a variable you didn't want because it's value includes `BUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. BTW: `declare -p` should properly quote, unlike `env` (unlikely to be a problem with this variable, though). Another option is to just write the value to the file, then use `read`. Or just use `echo` to write the assignment.

Comment: @Marco +1 Its working but could you shortly explain why I have to export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable while it is already set as env variable ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344377/7286) for a notify_all function which works from root crontab in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Note that I (on KDE on Arch) did also have to set `$DISPLAY`. Additionally, unlike most examples, my value was `DISPLAY=:0`, not `:0.0`. You can confirm this by echoing it from your normal user, and could put it in the same script that sets `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

Answer (score 20):

You need to set the variables in the crontab itself:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
XAUTHORITY=/home/matrix/.Xauthority

# m h  dom mon dow   command 
* * * * *  /usr/bin/notify-send "hello"
```

No `sudo` needed, at least not on my system.

Comment: Thanks terdon for your time. This seems to be a simple solution. Unfortunately, this didn't work for me,

Comment: @justsomeone huh, OK, might depend on the desktop environment then.

Comment: I think this has got something to do with distro or Desktop Environment. For Ubuntu users, the straight forward solutions seems to work fine from what I have seen in online forums.

Comment: @justsomeone I'm on Debian (LMDE) using Cinnamon as DE. Might have something to do with how X is started or with the notifications system used by the DE, dunno.

Comment: Confirmed it works on Ubuntu 14.04/14.10. With GNOME and Unity.

Comment: Does not work wich xubuntu 14.04. I wonder what's the difference to gnome/unity...

Answer (score 7):

The safest way to get X session related environmental variables is to get them from the environment of a process of the user who is logged on to X. Here is an adaptation of the script that I use for exactly the same purpose (although DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS doesn't seem to be a problem for me on Debian):

```
X=Xorg                   # works for the given X command
copy_envs="DISPLAY XAUTHORITY DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"

tty=$(ps h -o tty -C $X | head -1)
[ -z "$tty" ] && exit 1

# calling who with LANG empty ensures a consistent date format
who_line=$(LANG= who -u | grep "^[^ ]\+[ ]\+$tty")

x_user=$(echo $who_line | cut -d ' ' -f 1)  # the user associated with the tty
pid=$(echo $who_line | cut -d ' ' -f 7)     # the user's logon process

for env_name in $copy_envs
do
  # if the variable is not set in the process environment, ensure it does not remain exported here
  unset "$env_name"

  # use the same line as is in the environ file to export the variable
  export "$(grep -az "^$env_name=" /proc/$pid/environ)" >/dev/null
done

sudo -u "$x_user" notify-send "hello"
```

This sends to message to the first X user it finds, although you could add a loop to send it to all users.

### Update

It seems that updates to the utmp format cause `who` to print a display instead of a tty in its second column. This actually makes things easier, previously it only printed the display in the comment at the end and I decided this wasn't safe to rely on for the original answer. If this is the case, try this:

```
X=Xorg                   # works for the given X command
copy_envs="DISPLAY XAUTHORITY DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"

# calling who with LANG empty ensures a consistent date format
who_line=$(LANG= who -u | awk '$2 ~ ":[0-9]"')

x_user=$(echo $who_line | cut -d ' ' -f 1)  # the user associated with the tty
pid=$(echo $who_line | cut -d ' ' -f 7)     # the user's logon process

for env_name in $copy_envs
do
  # if the variable is not set in the process environment, ensure it does not remain exported here
  unset "$env_name"

  # use the same line as is in the environ file to export the variable
  export "$(grep -az "^$env_name=" /proc/$pid/environ)" >/dev/null
done

sudo -u "$x_user" notify-send "hello"
```

Answer (score 7):

This one-liner worked for me in Manjaro with Cronie:

```
# Note: "1000" would be your user id, the output of... "id -u <username>" 
10 * * * * pj DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus notify-send 'Hello world!' 'This is an example notification.'
```

Without the very ugly DBUS_blah_blah it doesn't work at all. I also found `journalctl -xb -u cronie` helpful. FWIW, Cronie uses crond and should be backward compatible with Vixie cron.

I found the solution here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications

Update: Still works in 2021. I add these tips to my /etc/crontab file.

```
# After installing cronie:
# systemctl start cronie
# systemctl enable cronie

# After editing this file:
# chmod 600 /etc/crontab    
# crontab /etc/crontab
# Check that the changes are set:
# crontab -l
```

Comment: what is `pj`? thanks anyway, this worked

Comment: @phil294 that's the username of the session where you want the notifications.

Comment: Worked in Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon

Answer (score 7):

I use i3 on Ubuntu 18.04. My way to solve this is:

`* * * * *  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) notify-send Hey "this is dog!"`

Comment: This worked for me on Wayland using Sway and Mako.

Comment: Worked on Gnome, Wayland as well (Fedora 39).

Answer (score 1):

This is sufficient to make notify-send work for me in a cronjob on Ubuntu Trusty:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=$(who -u | awk  '/\s:[0-9]\s/ {print $2}')
```

It simply exports the `DISPLAY` for the user the cronjob is running as.  It works for me without setting `XAUTHORITY` or `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04 as well.  I actually have cron launching a Perl script, which system()s a bash script, which launches a different Perl script, which performs a system("notify-send ...").  

Adding the export command to the bash script modified the environment for that script, which the last Perl script then inherited and made available to the system("notify-send ...").  Good find blujay!

Answer (score 1):

For those on Linux who are comfortable installing Python packages, I just released a [notify-send-headless](http://proc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-proc.notify) program which is working well for me. It searches `/proc` for the required username and environment variables and then runs `notify-send` with these variables (it will use `sudo` to switch to the required user if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
runuser -l [yourusername] -c 'DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "hey there user"'
```

Then run it with `sudo`. However, since `crontab -e` runs all commands with the user that created it, the following should suffice when called without `sudo`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "hey there user"
```

At least it does for me. It all seems to be dependent on the environment configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Use `printenv` for print environment variables from your normal terminal. And then paste all environment variables in starting of crontab file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was with using `root` user with `notify-send`. I realized this when I saw that `sudo notify-send` didn't work on the terminal but just `notify-send` (i.e. with current user) did.
So instead of editing the usual `/etc/crontab` which is used by `root`, I created a custom cron script for  `myusername` using the below command

```
sudo crontab -u myusername -e
```

And added the below command to trigger my `notify-send` script.

```
24 23 * * * bash /home/myusername/notify_send_script.sh
```

You can get your username with the command `id -u -n`. It's important to create a separate script instead of just the `notify-send` command as you'll also have to export the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` env variable.
I created my `/home/myusername/notify_send_script.sh` as below thanks to the simple script in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70642823/3972890) answer

```
#!/bin/bash
userid=$(id -u)
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$userid/bus"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
notify-send "Message title here" "Here goes the message"
```

Comment: Doesn't work, tried your steps on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I use this script in cron to post MPD now playing to twitter every hour

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
msg=$(mpc current -h 192.168.1.33)
twitter set "#MPD Server nowplaying $msg :  http://cirrus.turtil.net:9001"
#ttytter -status="#MPD Server nowplaying $msg. http://cirrus.turtil.net:9001"

exit
```

similar script using notify-send

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=":0.0"
notify-send -i ~/.icons/48arch.png 'OS- Archlinux x86_64 : DWM Window Manager' 'Installed on Sun Apr 21 2013 at 18:17:22' 
exit
```

you may be experiencing problems as KDE uses its own notify-deamon IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth....

I had to use ALL of the following on Debian Jessie to get this to work...

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export HOME=/home/$user
source "$HOME/.dbus/session-bus/*-0"
```

Leaving out any one of these caused it to stop working.

Comment: That last line won't do anything as written here, because there will be no file literally called `*-0` in your `session-bus` directory. You might have meant `source "$HOME"/.dbus/session-bus/*-0`.

Answer (score 0):

**Using sudo :**

```
sudo -u $currentxuser notify-send $message
```

**Tip :**

We can get the current x user by this command

```
ps auxw | grep -i screen | grep -v grep | cut -f 1 -d ' '
```

In addition...

```
currentxuser=$(ps auxw | grep -i screen | grep -v grep | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
echo $currentxuser
```

**Good to know :**

Cron running under root does not have access to x thus all gui commands will not be displayed, one simple solution is to add root to authorized x user for the current x user with this command

from the x user shell

```
xhost local:root
```

or

```
sudo -u $currentxuser xhost local:root
```

Comment: I don't know which command your "grep screen" catches - on my system it is a wrapper ... libscreenshotplugin.so and works therefore by accident. If you know, what you are searching, you may use -C to tell ps, what process to look for and -o to restrict the output like so: `ps -C xfce4-session -o user=`. Of course, xfce-session is specific to my xfce4-Desktop and needs to be changed for others.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a less complex script than what Graeme provided. His script didn't work for me, `$who_line` was always empty. My script doesn't waste so much time with finding a process. Instead, it just tries all and pick the last useful value found. I'm running xubuntu 14.04 and have some lxc containers running which probably confuse this kind of scripts.

```
env="$(
  ps -C init -o uid,pid | while read u p; do
    [ "$u" = "`id -u`" ] || continue
    grep -az '^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=' /proc/$p/environ | xargs -0
  done | tail -1
)"

export "$env"

notify-send "test"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Trusty because the Xorg process's environment doesn't have `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.  I can get it from my shells, but not from the Xorg process.