# udev action to call notify-send not working

Tags: shell-script, x11, udev, d-bus, notify-send

I have been trying to make a `udev` rule for a while, but without succes. For testing purposes, I have a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-power.rules` which contains

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/opt/eigen_scripts/waarschuwing_stroomkabel.sh"
```

Supposedly, this should run the specified script whenever a device like a USB stick is added (I monitored `udevadm` and the action indeed is `add` when plugging in a USB stick). This is not actually what I want to achieve in the end, but it seemed like the easiest way to at least get some kind of `udev` rule working. If you think the problem lies here, feel free to suggest an even simpler rule, I'd be glad to get any rule at all working.

The script in `/opt/eigen_scripts/waarschuwing_stroomkabel.sh` is

```
notify-send -i face-worried "Geen stroom!" "Sluit de adapter aan of de computer valt misschien uit."
```

and should send a notification.

Both files mentioned can be read and executed by root and all users. Using bash I have manually run the script in the second file (both as root and as normal user) and it works just fine. I have rebooted the system several times. I don't know what to try anymore. Thank you for your help.

I am working on a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

**Update:** I have been looking at the duplicate question and the links in the comments, but haven't gotten much wiser. Updating my script to the script

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=":0"
notify-send "device plugged"
```

and rebooting did not solve anything, while it did at least partially work for the dupplicate questions's OP. I tried to follow the steps in the first two answers of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root) but without effect. And I do not understand what [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147036/notify-send-not-working-under-ssh) is even about.

Comment: notify-send probably relies on the environment variables from your session to work... Have you tried something simpler, like a `touch /tmp/my-script-ran` and seeing if `/tmp/my-script-ran` gets created?

Comment: Also, make sure your script is executable (`chmod +x`). Probably should have a `#!/bin/sh` line up top too.

Comment: Both scripts were executable, but I changed the second one to `#!/bin/sh` as the first line and `tocuh /tmp/my-script-ran` as the second one and this worked after reboot. Thanks for the help. How could I get notify-send to work? It works if I just execute it from the terminal ...

Comment: `notify-send` needs the `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable from your desktop session. There are a few kludges to get it, search for a few and if none work ask a new question about it (or I suppose rewrite this one to be about it).

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root) and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147036/notify-send-not-working-under-ssh) are why your attempt didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it. What an awful lot of work to send a notification though.