# Create a notification on the screen initiated by root

Tags: d-bus, libnotify

I would like to give out a notification on screen by a script that is running by root on Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAINUSER=$(cat /etc/passwd|grep 1000|sed "s/:.*$//g")
su $MAINUSER -c 'notify-send "starting some scan... "'
#....
su $MAINUSER -c 'notify-send "scan finished "'
```

which works fine and creates a notification, if you run it as root in a terminal, that was started in the desktop screen, but it doesn't if you change to another screen with Ctrl+Alt+F1 to start it from there as root.

I also tried it with `export DISPLAY=:0; sudo -E -u rubo77 notify-send`, but that didn't change the behaviour either.

I would like to add it here in my script to [run rkhunter regularely on a desktop system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536762/run-rkhunter-regularely-on-a-desktop-system)

relevant discussion: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17882/discussion-between-rubo77-and-muru

I also tried to use [`xuserrun`](https://github.com/rephorm/xuserrun/issues/5) instead, but the same result

Comment: Maybe this is a hint how it could work: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=775170&p=6087197#post6087197#2 although it didn't plain like posted there and I don't hae the knowledge about DBUS

Comment: I use it with $USER which is set by the system

Comment: I'm sorry, did you deleted comments? Also your edit now show that `sudo -E` doesn't work, but it does

Comment: @Alex no it doesn't. The OP is running this from a separate session (a tty) where they have logged in as root. The `-E` will export root's environment, not the user's since `sudo` is being run by root. Using `-E` will only make this work if you run the script as the main user who started the X session. In that case, it works because the correct `XAUTHORITY` variable is exported.

Comment: @terdon there was a comment by @rubo77 where he wrote `sudo -E` was working. Also are you sure `XAUTHORITY` is necessary? I use just `xhost +` and with `su user -c` seems to work.

Comment: @Alex I deleted the comments since the information had been added to the question. The deleted comment was "yes export DISPLAY=:0; sudo -E -u rubo77 notify-send test works, but still only If I execute the script directly, not from cron". Again, that will only work if run as the user who started the X session, `-E` exports the environment of the user running `sudo`, if that was root, then it won't work. Yes, `xhost +` is enough (as I point out in my answer) but it is not secure and exporting `.Xauthority` is better. With `xhost +` _any_ user can connect to the running X session.

Comment: @terdon, I was using it (`sudo -E`) for crontab tasks (which should also correctly set HOME var `USER=$(basename $HOME)`) the `-E` is only to let DISPLAY live which otherwise would be discarded by sudo. Anyway good anwser, sorry I didn't ready it all before, good to know about XAUTHORITY I'll try.

Comment: @Alex yes but that's because you were using it in _your_ crontab and you were the owner of the X session. As I said, `sudo -E` exports the environment of the user who launched it. Your crontab will be run as you, if you try it as a different user (which is what the OP is doing) it won't work.

Comment: @Alex while the points I made were true, they seem to be irrelevant here because inotify-send works via D-bus and is not affected by the XAUTHORITY/xhosts stuff. Apparently.

Comment: The marked duplicate doesnt have such a nice answer like this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron

Comment: Please reopen this so I can post parts of the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/537721/34298