# Is revealing DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable a vulnerability?

Tags: security, d-bus

I found this instructions:

> [Using notify-send with cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/111190/20661)

Revealing the content of your `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` like in this answer gives access to **every user logged in** to your session:

```
#!/bin/sh

touch $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
chmod 600 $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
env | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
echo 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' >> $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus

exit 0
```

Wouldn't this be a security risk?

Comment: I've asked that this Q be migrated to U&L, since it's more on-topic there, and pairs with the linked Q that I A'ered already.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The directory that the files are contained within are permissioned so that only the owner of the directory can access them.

```
$ ls -ld ~/.dbus/
drwx------. 3 saml saml 4096 Jan  5  2014 /home/saml/.dbus/

$ ls -ld ~/.dbus/session-bus/
drwx------. 2 saml saml 4096 Jan 18  2014 /home/saml/.dbus/session-bus/

$ ls -ld ~/.dbus/session-bus/0ee868f8b7da40f48013a281826b1b84-*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 467 Mar 22  2014 /home/saml/.dbus/session-bus/0ee868f8b7da40f48013a281826b1b84-0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 477 May  4 03:35 /home/saml/.dbus/session-bus/0ee868f8b7da40f48013a281826b1b84-10
```

So without access to the upper directories, no user's besides the owner would be allowed to access anything underneath.