# Run script every 30 min with systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, services, scheduling

I would like to execute a script every 30 min after booting into the system. I know you can use cron, but I don't plan to use this feature often therefore I'd like to try it with systemd.

So far I have only found the monotonic timers which allows to execute something once (at least I think so). How would the `foo.timer` and `foo@user.service` look like in case I wanted to execute something every 30 minutes from boot/system start?

**foo@user.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=run foo
Wants=foo.timer

[Service]
User=%I
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/script.sh
```

**foo.timer**

```
[Unit]
Description=run foo

[Timer]
where I am stuck... ???
```

Answer (score 59):

You need to create two files: one for service, other for timer with same name.

example:

*/etc/systemd/system/test.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=test job

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /tmp/1.sh
```

*/etc/systemd/system/test.timer*

```
[Unit]
Description=test

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=10s
OnBootSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

after that reload the systemd using command `systemctl daemon-reload` and start your timer by `systemctl start test.timer`, or enable it by default (`systemctl enable test.timer`).

test content of `1.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `date` >> /tmp/2
```

And command to check all available timers:
`systemctl list-timers --all`

More detailed info on project [page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) and examples on [ArchLinux page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers)

Comment: systemd accepts the scripts and it is listed, however nothing is happening

Comment: which one? there should be two scripts, one timer and another service. Time, when they was executed could be checked by list-timers command, Possible errors could be checked by `systemctl status test.timer` and `systemctl status test.service` comamand

Comment: I added both scripts and reloaded the daemon. Then started `test.timer`. The status tells me that it is active (running) however nothing is happening.

Comment: please use `systemctl list-timers --all` command and check the output. He need to be like [this](http://pastebin.com/cteCmFGw). Look to unit, left and passed  columns. If timer is present, please look to your service file and check for bugs there since timer working normally.

Comment: Alright I figured it out.. you need `/bin/bash script.sh` as well as making the script executable. But unfortunately it doesn't trigger `notify-send` which creates notifications in `xfce4`

Comment: hah, this is another case. the problem is how notify-send works. utility send command through D-BUS, since in most cases notify services use session D-BUS, when you would run command outside of your desktop session - nothing will happen.  You should save somewhere $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS variable from your desktop session and export saved variable in your systemd script. And sure, you need run script under same user as your desktop one.

Comment: I thought so! Do you mind extending your answer?

Comment: no, coz main question doesn't ask nothing about "notify-send" and i think we should not mix two different things when such [topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron)  already present.
in your case, try to add `export DISPLAY=:0.0` to the script.

Comment: ps: according to man systemd.timer  the Persistent=true only has an effect on configured with OnCalendar (i.e. wallclock)

Comment: @snyh thx, and looks like OnUnitActiveSec is related to monotonic timers so we can safely remove  Persistent=true which belongs to OnCalendar  :)  Will edit post

Comment: Where is 30min set in your example?

Comment: @KarlMorrison it is set to 10s in example, change value to 30min for full satisfaction expirience

Comment: I am missing something here. How does the timer know that the test.service is to be run?

Comment: @Dagelf `[unit name].[type of service]` i.e.   we have unit name `test` with service types `service` and `timer`.     What would be triggered available as well via systemctl status test.timer. So answering bluntly, by filename before dot ...

Comment: `.timer` will never fire with *only* `OnUnitActiveSec=` when its `Unit=.service` is `Type=oneshot`: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6680

Answer (score 24):

Here is another option without using your timer.  If timing is not terribly critical and and script isn't long running it will be fine for simple things.

```
[Unit]
Description=Run foo

[Service]
User=%I
Restart=always
RestartSec=1800s
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/script.sh
```

Comment: I like this solution.  The only major drawback is that system logs will be flooded with "Starting <service X>" logs if you restart often (i.e. every 30 seconds).  At which point it might be better to run the service as a daemon instead, instead of restarting the service over and over from systemd.

Comment: That's true.  For quick and simple stuff it works.  But the timer or a long running script would be a better solution.

Answer (score 10):

The proper way is to use `systemd-run` you can schedule your job without the need to define your own unit.

It allows you to schedule by a calendar or every period of time. Assuming MYSELF is your full path application:

```
systemd-run --user --on-calendar '*:0/1' ${MYSELF} <args>
```

Comment: Does this run "every 30 minutes from boot/system start"? How would the OP adapt it to do that?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm about to try this out, but it looks like OP's requirement could be met with `systemd-run --on-boot=1800 --on-unit-active=1800 /home/user/script.sh`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as op stated he wants to run a script, not explicitly create a service and a timer. `systemd-run` does that in the background without the user noticing.