# Where do I put scripts executed by systemd units?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, directory-structure

For any OS that uses systemd to manage processes and follows the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard by the Linux Foundation](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html)

I recently asked where to but a systemd unit file: 
[Where do I put my systemd unit file on Arch Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/224992/33386)

I would like to run a **python script** every 5 minutes (not to be confused with a systemd unit file script that calls the python script). I read the answers to this question:
[Run script every 30 min with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198444/run-script-every-30-min-with-systemd)

This is where my question comes in. Where should or could you store scripts that are run by systemd? Is there a reserved place for these, particularly on Arch Linux?

- For example, logs are placed in `/var/log`
- `systemd` unit files are placed under `/etc/systemd/system`

## /etc/systemd/system/writehello.service

Here is an example service.

```
[Unit]
Description=Run python script that writes hello in file on /media/5TB/hello.txt

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=# <-- This is what I am looking for

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## /etc/systemd/system/writehello.timer

Here is a corresponding timer. This is all stuff documented.

```
[Unit]
Description=test

[Timer]
Persistent=true
OnUnitActiveSec=10s
OnBootSec=10s

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

## /path/to/writehello.py

**This is the path I am looking for.**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

f1 = open('/media/mydrive/hello.txt','a')
f1.write('hello %s\n' % (now))
f1.close
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also was thinking about this same question and wanted to see other's opinion. My take on it is `/usr/local/sbin` as `sbin` is where you put things that should be run by admin.

Your analysis is correct the `/usr/local` is the location dedicated for installing stuff not managed by package manager. But `bin` is for stuff that should be runnable by regular users. In either case, you should not allow write access to anybody but `root` to the files in `/usr/local`. That's the convention as far as I remember (for the whole /usr/).

`/opt` is usually used for packages that are not used by default on the system and user should set some environment variables to access by bin/man/etc. directories of specific package. Read the links I've provided above.

See [RHEL FSH overview](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html-single/Storage_Administration_Guide/index.html#s1-filesystem-fhs) as well the [latest FHS documentation](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/).

Answer (score 7):

Here are the ideal locations for storing things that will be run (see links for details):

Quote from the File System Hierarchy Standard HS v2.3

> Locally installed system administration programs should be placed in /usr/local/sbin.

I understood that when FHS documentation refers to "system", it is referring to some "root" user.

1. [`/usr/local/bin` OR `/usr/local/sbin`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html) **unique** to this computer (not available to a package manager, e.g. scripts, software from a CD) i.e. not installed from a common source to all computers (**not a package manager**). `/usr/local/bin` stuff can be run by all users. `/usr/local/sbin` stuff can be run by root only (it is the system "binary" directory).
2. [`/usr/bin`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s04.html) **not unique** (shared stuff between computers e.g. from a package manager i.e. **a package manager uses this location**)
3. [`/root/bin`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s14.html) a **root user** could create this directory instead of using `/usr/local/sbin`. It is a good place to store things that only a **root user** runs OR can see (this folder is only executable by root or group root, therefore its contents is not visible to anyone except root) You could even make a bin folder in there to keep things consistent, but no one would know anyway :)
4. [`/home/<user>/bin`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s08.html) **a standard user** could create this directory. It is a good place to store scripts that are run as a standard user by systemd.

The conclusion is that **number 1** would be an ideal place to store scripts that are run by a systemd daemon/service.

It makes sense,

1. it is a standard location
2. it is isolated from your package manager packages

Answer (score 0):

You can store your scripts in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` (preferred) or `/opt`

You have to refer to script in  `ExecStart=` key In service section of unit file