# Systemd unit's ExecStartPre with script gives error, how to specify the path to the script?

Tags: systemd, services

There's a script which has to be run by a systemd service's `ExecStartPre`. What would be the proper path to put this script into and how to specify it in the unit?
Currently using paths such as these fail (the service won't start due to bad unit file):

- script.sh
- ./script.sh
- /etc/systemd/system/script.sh
- /usr/local/sbin/script.sh

Here's the error I get in the status:

> Process: 8679 ExecStartPre=/usr/local/sbin/script.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

And here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -e /var/log/myservice ];
        then
                echo "myservice's log directory doesn't exist. creating it."
                mkdir /var/log/myservice
fi
```

Comment: `ExecStartPost` or `ExecStartPre`? Where is the script actually located?

Comment: Fixed it now, I'd tested many times so the log was slightly different. The script is in /usr/local/sbin/

Comment: Is the script actually executable?

Comment: Ah silly me thank you muru. Yes  chmod +x fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don’t need to change your script, the advice [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245834/86440) applies: the script should go in `/usr/local/sbin`. It also needs to be executable. Your `ExecStartPre` would be

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/sbin/script.sh
```

However you don’t need a script at all to create a directory:

```
ExecStartPre=mkdir -p /var/log/myservice
```

Better yet, use [`LogsDirectory=`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.exec.5.html#SANDBOXING), which will create the directory if necessary and ensure it’s available inside the sandbox if the service is sandboxed:

```
LogsDirectory=myservice
```

Comment: I thought `p` was for creating the parents, but I didn't know about `-p, --parents no error if existing...`. Great! Thanks.

Comment: The keen eyed can spot the systemd way of doing this at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/567317/5132 .  (-:

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @JdeBP, I thought there was something like that but couldn’t find it.