# Notify-send doesn't work at Cinnamon

Tags: cron, cinnamon, notifications, notify-send

I am using `Linux Mint 17`.
I want to be informed every 50 min, at every hour for small break.

Here is ***cron job***:

```
nazar@desktop ~ $ crontab -l

DISPLAY=:0.0
XAUTHORITY=/home/matrix/.Xauthority

00 13 * * * /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/lunch_break_job.sh # JOB_ID_2
50 * * * * /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/pc_break.sh # JOB_ID_1
* * * * * /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/cron_job_test.sh # JOB_ID
```

Here is script for `/home/nazar/Documents/scripts/cron_job_test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=0.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/matrix/.Xauthority

if [ -r "$HOME/.dbus/Xdbus" ]; then
  . "$HOME/.dbus/Xdbus"
fi

/usr/bin/notify-send -i "hello"
```

This snippet of function:

```
if [ -r "$HOME/.dbus/Xdbus" ]; then
  . "$HOME/.dbus/Xdbus"
fi
```

Checks `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and uses it.

[According to this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron) I executed script, and now my `Dbus` is saved to `$HOME/.dbus/Xdbus`:

```
nazar@desktop ~ $ cat $HOME/.dbus/Xdbus
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-flm7sXd0I4,guid=df48c9c8d751d2785c5b31875661ebae
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

All should work. I couldn't find what is missed. Because notification doesn't work now.

From terminal it works fine:

[image]

***How to solve this issue?***

**SOLUTION:**

Now my `crontab` looks as follows:

```
DISPLAY=":0.0"
XAUTHORITY="/home/nazar/.Xauthority"
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
00 13 * * * /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/lunch_break_job.sh # JOB_ID_2
50 * * * * /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/pc_break.sh # JOB_ID_1
# * * * * * /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/cron_job_test.sh # JOB_ID
```

and `cron_job_test.sh` looks now:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/notify-send -i /home/nazar/Pictures/icons/Mail.png "hello" "It is just cron test message"
```

`pc_break.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/notify-send -i /home/nazar/Pictures/icons/download_manager.png "Break:" "Make a break for 10 min"
```

`lunch_break_job.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/notify-send -i /home/nazar/Pictures/icons/Apple.png "Lunch: " "Please, take a lunch!"
```

Comment: actually the script is not correctly working is the one should notify every 50 min right? but you didn't showed to us the `/home/nazar/Documents/scripts/pc_break.sh` script. Maybe there is an error in there ?

Comment: Have you tried to run the script in crontab as your user `nazar`?
`50 * * * * nazar /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/pc_break.sh # JOB_ID_1`

Comment: @lese I want clarify that I post firstly my problem and show some test example. `pc_break` job and script are correct. And this job `cron_job_test.sh` is just test to verify if cron works, in general.

Comment: @syss After your comment I have already tried. And this doesn't work. Job looks correct to cron job wiki info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` as well. Change your crontab to this:

```
DISPLAY=":0.0"
XAUTHORITY="/home/nazar/.Xauthority"
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1001"
00 13 * * * /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/lunch_break_job.sh # JOB_ID_2
50 * * * * /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/pc_break.sh # JOB_ID_1
* * * * * /home/nazar/Documents/scripts/cron_job_test.sh # JOB_ID
```

Make sure you change `nazar` to whatever your username is and `1001` to your actual UID. You can get your UID by running `id -u`.

And all you need in your script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/notify-send "hello"
```

I just tested this on Arch running Cinnamon and it worked fine.

The variables are being set in the crontab, no need to export anything from the script. There's also no point in doing so, the script is being called by cron, it wouldn't export the values you need anyway.

Comment: thanks for such great answer. But it doesn't want work on Linux Mint 17. I couldn't guess why.

Comment: @nazar_art did you use my username or yours? Also, the `1001` should be your UID. You can find out what yours is by running `id -u`.

Comment: I had deleted redundant lines from `crontab` and now it works.