# bash : send rsync status using notify-send

Tags: bash, rsync, notifications

I'm using `rsync` to push some changes to a server, for that I made a bash script and I want to show a status notification in the desktop (I'm using Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon)

Is it possible to send the output of `rsync` to `notify-send` so I can see the amount of data synchronized? Here is my actual bash script:

```
notify-send "sincronizando esteticas"
rsync -tprvkku --exclude "00_docs" --exclude "temp" --exclude "config.php" --progress public_html/ rsync://myserver:/myfiles 
notify-send "sincronizacion terminada"
```

Comment: Have you tried this? As written there's no particular reason why this wouldn't work. If it doesn't please explan how you're running it (remember to [update your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/316864/edit) with this extra information).

Comment: Depending on how this script is being run it's a possible duplicate of [Using notify-send with cron](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron)

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the progress bar in the notify during the rsync?

Comment: Not the progress bar.. the output that rsync shows on the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a notify popup holding the final summary line, something like

```
sent 6,673,231 bytes  received 17,718 bytes  13,381,898.00 bytes/sec
total size is 6,613,892  speedup is 0.99
```

then you can capture the rsync output into a file, and use the last 2 lines of the file:

```
rsync ... | tee /tmp/out
notify-send "$(tail -2 /tmp/out)"
```

If you would like a more detailed summary, add `--info=stats2`

```
rsync --info=stats2 ... | tee /tmp/out
notify-send "$(tail -16 /tmp/out)"
```

This will provide extra info such as:

```
Number of files: 932 (reg: 929, dir: 2, link: 1)
Number of created files: 932 (reg: 929, dir: 2, link: 1)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 929
Total file size: 6,613,892 bytes
Total transferred file size: 6,613,888 bytes
Literal data: 6,613,888 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 6,673,231
Total bytes received: 17,686
```