# systemd service not executing the python script

Tags: systemd, python, raspberry-pi, libnotify, notify-send

I was making a battery notifier script for my raspberry pi3. The script is executing when I do

```
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/shutdown.py
```

and showing the popup notifications.  However the service is not executing it or not showing the notification.  I can see the python process if I do `sudo systemctl status battery-notifier.service`.

### battery-notifer.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Battery Notifier

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Documents
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/shutdown.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### shutdown.py

```
import raspiupshat
import statistics
import subprocess
from time import sleep
raspiupshat.init()
while(True):
    voltagesList = []
    sleep(0.5)
    currentVoltage = raspiupshat.getv()
    voltagesList.append(currentVoltage)
    medianVoltage = statistics.median(voltagesList)
    if(medianVoltage>4):
        subprocess.Popen(["notify-send","Battery Full!"])
```

This is the status of the service when I do `sudo systemctl status battery-notifier.service`:

```
● battery-notifier.service - Battery Notifier
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/battery-notifier.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-07-15 04:05:18 UTC; 48min ago
 Main PID: 28384 (python)
   CGroup: /system.slice/battery-notifier.service
           └─28384 /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/shutdown.py

Jul 15 04:05:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Battery Notifier.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using notify-send with cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron)

Comment: how do I set the dbus session env variable in python script? Tried `subprocess.call("export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-goOEk5dZcK,guid=9c1f14175e6be0992b16e5155969b46c",shell=True) `,but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe, this points to a design issue. A command which is executed by a system process (by systemd) is supposed to directly manipulate the session of a user. What if there are multiple users logged in? Maybe it's more appropriate if you either implement the whole battery checker to be started when the user logs in, or you make the systemd task just write a message to the system-wide dbus (via `dbus-send`) and each logged in user must then launch a program (for example in Python via using the `dbus` package) which listens to that message to display something on the screen of their desktop?

Comment: Finally it worked! Yes you are right @akraf .Mentioning the `User=pi` in the service worked as a charm! Please edit your original answer with this so that it can help others too.

Comment: Glad that it worked! However, that was not my intention, I did not even know a `User=` systemd parameter existed :-). So the credits would be undeserved. My idea was to develop two separate programs, the first at system level which deals with checking the battery status and the second started at user login which is notified by the first and displays the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited to add**: Your program tries to access the graphical desktop of a user (`pi`), however, it is itself executed by systemd. That is, it will run as root per default and not as the user `pi`. Moreover, there might not even be a graphical desktop yet at the time this is started.

Therefore, you could go several paths:

- Start the program not via systemd, but when the logged in user starts the 
  graphical desktop. Therefore, you need to put the program start into the 
  file `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xprofile`. See [the Arch Wiki on Autostart](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autostarting)
- Add a line `User=pi` to your systemd service. This is the solution you mentioned in the comment to your original post
- systemd can be configure to be executed in a user-mode (as opposed to system mode) when the user logs in. You could let your service be started by that way. See [the Arch Wiki on systemd/User](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User)

---

**Original answer:**

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment). There is an `env=` parameter in the `subprocess.Popen(.)` function which can be used.

Alternatively, you could use the feature of `sh` that if you assign a variable immediately before a call, that variable is set (only) for that call:

```
myvar=world
# cannot use echo $myvar, because $myvar would be substituted before echo is launched
myvar=hello declare -x myvar 
echo $myvar
```

gives

```
declare -x myvar="hello"
world
```

[Link to corresponding chapter in POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01)

So for you:

```
subprocess.call("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-goOEk5dZcK,‌​guid=9c1f14175e6be09‌​92b16e5155969b46c notify-send 'Battery full!'",s‌​hell=True)
```

The call you mentioned in the comment to your question does not work because it leads to the following process

- `subprocess.Popen('export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADRESS=..., shell = True)`

  - Launch a shell
  - Set the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADRESS=...` for this shell
    and all sub-shells (that's what `export` does).

    What it does **NOT**: Set the variable for all shells there are on the machine!
  - Close the shell. Now the value of `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADRESS` is lost again.
- `subprocess.Popen(['notify-send',...], shell=True)`

  - Launch a shell
  - The `export` call of the previous shell has no power here because these two shells are completely unrelated
  - Launch `notify-send` as in your original question

So the setting of the environment variable has no effect here.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work.I used `subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', 'Battery Full!'],env={'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS':'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-RTLFkePIFz,guid=c576b8a74fdd67955e5abbb05969f3cd'})`  However running the python script alone is working and was working before `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` added too!

Comment: Hm... you could try the other variables which were mentioned in @jasonwryan's comment, for example `DISPLAY` or `XAUTHORITY`... it would be awesome if you could leave a short notice if any of those works...