# Unable to send notifications from cron job

Tags: scripting, cron, notifications

I'm trying to use a cron job to see when the battery gets lower than a given threshold, and then to send a battery critical notification. However, when I make the cron job execute a script every minute, and make the script send me a notification, it doesn't work.

To make sure that it's not a permissions issue with the script or something causing the cron job to not run, I made the script create a file instead, and it worked. This is the crontab entry:

```
* * * * * /home/aravk/test.sh
```

And, to simplify the problem, these are the contents of `test.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/dunstify hi
```

No notification shows up, however. The script does work when I execute it manually. I also tried setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable to `:0` by changing the crontab entry to `* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/aravk/test.sh`, but it still didn't work. How do I send notifications from a script executed by a cron job? I'm on Arch Linux, if it's relevant.

Comment: What's output of running `/usr/bin/dunstify hi`? Make sure `libnotify` is installed.

Comment: @TuyenPham it shows a notification saying `hi`. Like I said in the question, the script does work when I execute it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added this to my crontab and all my notifications work (currently tested with **zenity** and **notify-send**):

```
DISPLAY=":0.0"
XAUTHORITY="/home/me/.Xauthority"
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

Comment: Holy shit, that worked!! Only the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` variable seems to be necessary for notifications, though

Comment: I kept it the same as root's crontab ,  where it was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the crontab job access to some environment variables..
I just solved this probleme in my Kali Linux, so open terminal and type `export` hit enter and a message with info of the variables will show up..

get to the line where `declare -x DISPLAY=":1"` exists (value may be 0 not 1)
just copy the `DISPLAY=":1"` and past it in your crontab line, then go to the line where `declare -x XAUTHORITY="/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority"` exists and copy this part `XAUTHORITY="/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority"`, then past that one too in your crontab line..

your crontab would be like:

`* * * * * DISPLAY=':1' XAUTHORITY='/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority' your_command`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with using `root` user with `notify-send`. I realized this when I saw that `sudo notify-send` didn't work on the terminal but just `notify-send` (i.e. with current user) did.
So instead of editing the usual `/etc/crontab` which is used by `root`, I had a custom cron script created for  `myusername`. Please check my whole answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710326/534253).