# Run systemd service with root access in the user session

Tags: systemd, root, services, d-bus, notifications

I am creating a systemd service that sends a desktop notification via `org.freedesktop.Notifications` dbus target whenever a high priority event is logged. To do so, I run `journalctl` as root and process the output all within a Rust program (`journalctl` is called as a child from within the program), which can be approximated as follows:

```bash
sudo journalctl -focat -p3 -Snow | xargs -I{} -d '\n' notify-send {}
```

I need to run `journalctl` with root privileges in order to have access to all of the logs, but when I make it a systemd service, it no longer works (also does not work when running with `sudo` in the terminal). My (abbreviated) `.service` file for it looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Requires=dbus.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=~
ExecStart=/usr/bin/auditnotify
Restart=always
PrivateTmp=true
NoNewPrivileges=true

[Install]
Alias=auditnotify
WantedBy=default.target
```

After inspecting the service with `strace`, I found out that what appears to be happening is that the [`zbus`](https://lib.rs/crates/zbus) dependency of the notification crate I am using, [`notify-rust`](https://lib.rs/crates/notify-rust), is getting the UID and then trying to get the session bus using that. However, since it's running as root, it gets 0 for its UID and fails to send the notification.

`strace` output snippet:

```
geteuid()                               = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/user/0/bus"}, 18) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
```

This hypothesis was confirmed when I added `User=gfaster` and `Group=gfaster` to the `.service` file, and notifications started working. However, as I mentioned earlier, this does not work since I need root access to the journal.

Is there any way of fixing this? Is it possible to run this service as part of the user session but with root privileges? Would I just have to make a second service that interfaces with the log, and if so, what does that configuration look like?

Comment: While my answer here was specific to `crontab`, you should be able to use the environment entries in a `systemd` service: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560724/unable-to-send-notifications-from-cron-job/560732#560732

Comment: hove you tried setting uid of `user gfaster` to 0 ?
`vi /etc/passwd`
`gfaster:0:0`

Comment: I don't think setting my user account to UID 0 is a good idea because that's already used by root on Linux systems.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I tried that and it seems like messages started being rejected due to authentication failure, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/194308/545231

Comment: What happens if you open a root terminal, add the variables in my post, then run your command manually? Obviously you changed `/home/me` to `/home/gfaster`, correct?

Comment: I did change it properly. Running `sudo -E ./auditnotify` after putting in all the variables still produces the broken pipe error.

Comment: As a test, disable access control with `xhost +` as your user, then try again. I just tested a simple `zenity` command and it worked.

Comment: You could give your user access to the journalctl logs.