# Remotely control an xorg session

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11, remote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open a window on a remote X display (why “Cannot open display”)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display)

I have a computer running debian, connected to my TV, running an xorg session. What I want to do is ssh into that machine and start an application that will also display on that machine. For example, I want to be able to ssh to it from my laptop and start mplayer on the host, playing a file on the host and showing it on the TV. Is this possible? I have a feeling it should be (relatively) trivial, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Just to clarify, simply running

```
$ ssh -X host
$ mplayer movie.avi &
```

won't cut it, because it will start displaying on my laptop's display.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know what `$DISPLAY` your ssh host's X server is using, e.g. `:0.0`, the following works for me:

```
ssh host
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Now you can run any graphical app of your choice on your host.  You won't be able to see or control the graphical aspects on/from your laptop, of course.

Comment: To find the corresponding `DISPLAY`, ssh to the host and invoke the command `w` which will show the users logged in and what they are doing.

Comment: @erik: How would the output of `w` tell you what's the right `DISPLAY`?

Comment: @einpoklum: If I run the `w` command, I get the following output: `21:31:00 up 23:13,  1 user,  load average: 0,50, 0,51, 0,50
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
erik     :0         Fr22   ?xdm?  12:39   0.65s gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]`, where `TTY` displays my current display (`:0`) and the `USER` the current user who started that X-server (`erik`).

Answer (score 2):

Another tip to place the program in background and detached from the ssh session:

```
ssh host '(DISPLAY=:0.0 mplayer movie.avi >/dev/null </dev/null 2>&1  &)'
```