# Calling xrandr via SSH

Tags: ssh, xorg, xrandr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open a window on a remote X display (why “Cannot open display”)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display)

I'd like to ssh to a host running an X server and use `xrandr` to query and update things related to that host's display. I don't forward X connections (no `-X`), but `xrandr` keeps saying it can't find the display. Invoked locally on that host, `xrandr` works as intended.

How do I make `xrandr` ignore the fact that I'm logged in remotely, and just operate on the host on which it is running?