# How can I connect to a remote X server _without_ ssh?

Tags: xorg, remote

I am very happy with *ssh -X* when I'm connecting to my machine over internet. But at home, I want to connect with my notebook to my desktop machine without ssh. What's the best way of doing this? (Both machines run Linux, Xubuntu.)

Comment: Please clarify your question. Exactly what is it that you want to be able to do?

Comment: Use my local machine as X server with a remote one (on LAN), without SSH.

Comment: Why not use ssh? It's the right tool for the job.

Comment: SSH is a kinda overhead, especially for tiny machines, like Raspberry Pi. Other reason: simple is beautiful.

Comment: This setup is very useful when using a host X display to connect to VM clients on the same physical server over a private internal network. In such a configuration, the host X display is an X terminal for connecting to the client VM's. For this configuration, SSH has no security value, and VNC or qemu graphics both reduce functionality of the display and add huge overhead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to run a `X` command on a remote system and and show the client
on your local system the solution is rather simple:

- You have to ensure that your X Server accepts connection via `TCP`,
  nowadays this is typically disabled as it is a
  security problem. You basically have to run your  Xorg server without the
  `-nolisten tcp` option.  For `gdm3` you can add `DisallowTCP=false` to
  `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf` under the security context. Afterwards you have to
  restart gdm3. Now `ps axuf | grep Xorg` should show your X-Server without
  the `-nolisten tcp` option.

  Now your XServer should listen on port `6000`, you can check with `netstat
  -anp | grep 600.`
- You have to allow access from your remote system to your local Xsession,
  this can be either done via `xhost` to generally allow access from a
  specific system, e.g. `xhost +host` or via supplying the magic cookie,
  see [DISPLAY and AUTHORITY](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10126/8979)
  for more information.
- Now you just have to specify the `DISPLAY` variable on your remote host,
  e.g: `export DISPLAY=localsystem:0`. Now all x clients will
  automatically try to use your local system. If you didn't allow TCP
  access (or have a firewall in between) or you didn't provide the needed
  authorization (e.g. wrong `xhost` command, did not copy the xauth
  cookie) your commands won't be able to connect to your system.

Please be aware that the connection is *not* encrypted and you basically
typing plaintext. If you use `xhost` you also allowed all clients from that
specific host access to your Xserver, e.g. they can read keyboard inputs etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ssh, then you can use tools like, `Remote Desktop Client`, `Connect to Server` and `Desktop Sharing` which are by default installed in your Kubuntu desktop editions.

**Edit:**
I would recommend you to use `Remmina Remote Desktop Client` to connect to any VNC server running somewhere else.

Comment: Does desktop sharing use X?

Comment: @ern0: use the Remmina Remote Desktop Client, that uses X.

Comment: `ssh -x` is not really related to connecting to a remote desktop, it is used to execute X applications remotely and show the content on the host

Comment: I know what is X, I'm using it since 1980 (but never configured)

Answer (score -1):

teamviewer is fine for these kind of connections