# Is 'xhost local' (no colon) allowing malicious access?

Tags: networking, security, x, xhost

I'm setting up a new system and need to grant the root user authority to access the nonroot user's X display in order to run GUI utilities. I used the `xhost` command for this as follows, but ***mistakenly*** leaving off the colon suffix seems to have allowed access to the remote server `lb.usemaxserver.de`...

```
  nonroot@host2:~  xhost -
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
  nonroot@host2:~  xhost local
local being added to access control list
  nonroot@host2:~  xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
INET:lb.usemaxserver.de
INET:localhost
```

I've used the following to remove it...

```
  nonroot@host2:~  xhost -INET:lb.usemaxserver.de
lb.usemaxserver.de being removed from access control list
```

Am I interpreting this correctly?

If so, how did `lb.usemaxserver.de` setup something so that `local` links to that addess?

Does this require there to be some malicious configuration or software already on my system? If so, any suggestions for where to look?

Comment: A better way is to use MIT-auth cookies. Figure out where the X server you start gets his cookies from, and give this cookie to root, with `xauth` or other methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm setting up a new system and need to grant the root user authority to access the nonroot user's X display in order to run GUI utilities.

It sounds like you want `xhost +si:localuser:root`. (This is not available on all X implementations.  `man Xsecurity` also says that it is not entirely effective on some implementations.  But it seems better than `+local:`)

Also, your X server was probably not directly accessible from the network anyway.  E.g. see [How can I connect to a remote X server _without_ ssh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44818/how-can-i-connect-to-a-remote-x-server-without-ssh/44824#44824)

> I used the xhost command for this as follows, but ... seems to have allowed access to the remote server `lb.usemaxserver.de`

`xhost +local` looks up the hostname `local`, so it depends what you have in your DNS search path etc.

```
$ xhost +local
xhost:  bad hostname "local"
$ dig local
...
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
...
```

It sounds like your system resolves `local`, to a couple of different hosts.  Compare:

```
$ xhost +smtp.gmail.com
smtp.gmail.com being added to access control list
$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
INET6:wr-in-x6d.1e100.net
INET:wr-in-f108.1e100.net
INET:wr-in-f109.1e100.net
SI:localuser:alan
$ dig smtp.gmail.com
...
smtp.gmail.com.     104 IN  CNAME   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com. 104 IN A   108.177.15.108
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com. 104 IN A   108.177.15.109
...
$ dig AAAA smtp.gmail.com
smtp.gmail.com.     170 IN  CNAME   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com. 271 IN AAAA    2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6c
$ dig -x 2a00:1450:400c:c0c::6c
c.6.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.c.0.c.0.c.0.0.4.0.5.4.1.0.0.a.2.ip6.arpa. 300 IN PTR wr-in-x6c.1e100.net.
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. I've also determined that the "local = lb.usemaxserver.de" was due to entries in `/etc/hosts`. It's an antiX 17.1 distro that includes adblocking by zeroing out hundreds of addresses in that file and there were some erroneous entries.

Comment: @DocSalvager that's hilarious, thank you for the followup :-D.