# Xlib: No protocol specified

Tags: linux, x11, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open a window on a remote X display (why “Cannot open display”)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display)

I have a script that when run independently works that needs X11 Display variables to be set.
When I invoke this script using a background daemon job, I get the following error.
`Xlib: connection to "localhost.localdomain:0.0" refused by server`
`Xlib: No protocol specified`

Please help me identifying the possible mistake that I have in this.
 Commands given below which is inside the script.
`export DISPLAY=`hostname`:0.0`
`java ScreenCapture` 
If the same script is invoked by a background daemon running as a service, I get the error.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just guessing here, but the background daemon might be running as different user, which does not have permission to access the display.

You can use `xhost` to control user access:

> The xhost program is used to add and delete host names or user names
>   to the list allowed to make connections to the X server.

You can test if this is the problem by running:

```
xhost +
```

from a terminal window, which will allow any user to access the display.

`xhost +`(insert username here)

will allow access for a specific user.