# Strange crontab-script interaction (bash)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and bash. I've written a pair of shell scripts that allow me to set an alarm which, after ringing, unsets itself. The first, `alarmset`, allows me to enter a time and modifies the alarm line in my user crontab. That line launches the second script, `alarmring`, which launches a radio player in a browser window and then comments out the alarm line in the crontab.

`alarmring` is behaving strangely. If I run it myself directly, it performs both actions: it launches the browser window and edits the crontab. But if I run `alarmset`, when the crontab launches `alarmring` at the appointed time, `alarmring` edits the crontab, but does not launch the browser window.

Finally, when crontab runs `alarmring`, it ignores the `set -x` command, whereas when I run it directly, `set -x` is executed. So it's as though the crontab is skipping the first ten lines.

Any ideas on what's going on? I'll paste the two scripts and the crontab below.

**alarmset:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# alarmset

set -x

usage()
{ echo "alarmset [ hour minute | -h ]" }

editcrontab() 
{ 
    echo $'/alarmring/s/^\(.*\)\(\* \* \*\)/'$2$' '$1$' \\2/' > ~/Documents/crontab_script.txt 
    crontab -l | sed --file=/home/username/Documents/crontab_script.txt > ~/Documents/new_crontab.txt crontab ~/Documents/new_crontab.txt 
}

### MAIN 
case $# in 
    2 ) editcrontab $1 $2 ;; 
    * ) usage 
        exit ;; 
esac

set +x
```

**alarmring:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# alarmring

set -x

env DISPLAY=:0

# Ring the alarm : launch BBC World Service in Firefox 
firefox --new-window http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_world_service

# Unset the alarm : comment out the alarm line in the crontab 
crontab -l | sed '/alarmring/s/^/#/1' > ~/Documents/new_crontab.txt 
crontab ~/Documents/new_crontab.txt

set +x
```

**crontab:**

```
SHELL=/bin/bash 
PATH=~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin 
# 
# m h dom mon dow command 
53 07 * * * /home/username/bin/alarmring
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entries in the systems crontab (`/etc/crontab`) or to the directories (`/etc/cron.d` -or- `/etc/cron.hourly`, etc.) run as root. It's probably the case that root doesn't have the ability to access a given user's display by default.

I'd suggest making crontab entries using the user's ability to add crontabs. This can be accomplished by using the command `crontab -e` in a shell logged in as the specified user.

The command `crontab -e` will open a text editor (usually `vi` or `vim`) where you can add entries using the same syntax that you'd use to add entries to the systems `/etc/crontab` file.

This [tutorial covers the basics of adding crontab entires](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/).

Also when adding a user's crontab via `crontab -e` and your script needs access to your display (say you're launching a GUI), you'll need to set the environment variable (`export DISPLAY=:0.0`) so that the GUI get's directed to the correct display.

#### For example

```
% crontab -e
```

And add the following line:

```
53 07 * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0;/home/username/bin/alarming
```

Comment: This isn't a system crontab, though; it's my user crontab. I'll clarify.

Comment: I had to add a semicolon, so that it now reads `53 07 * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0;/home/username/bin/alarming`. But, yes, that worked. Thank you. Go ahead & make it an answer.

Comment: Yeah I should've mentioned that. You can also wrap the entire line in it's own script. Glad it worked, updated my answer to include the additional details.

Comment: Note to the curious: I've learned that, in Ubuntu/Debian, this task is nicely handled by [the `at` command.](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=at&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+6.0+squeeze&format=html&locale=en)

Comment: the at command is ubiquitous across pretty much all the unices.

Answer (score 3):

To run a GUI program, you need to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable, and possibly `XAUTHORITY` as well. See
[Open a window on a remote X display (why "Cannot open display")?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126) for more information.

`~` meaning your home directory is a shell feature, you can't use it in a crontab. For the same reason, you can't use `HOME`. Use the full path for your home directory:

```
PATH=/home/username/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

With bash as your shell, `~` actually works, because bash expands `~` in the value of `PATH`. But that's an oddity of bash, no other shell or other program works this way.

The command `env DISPLAY=:0` displays the current environment, except with `DISPLAY` set to `:0`. That isn't useful. You presumably meant `export DISPLAY=:0`.

Your arrangement is very complicated. Cron is designed for repeating tasks. If you want to schedule a background job just once, use [at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(Unix)).

```
at 7:53 <<EOF
firefox --new-window http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/bbc_world_service
EOF
```

At retains the `DISPLAY` environment variable, so provided you run the `at` command from the GUI where you want Firefox to display a window, you don't need to set it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ xauth extract - :0 | sudo xauth -f /root/.Xauthority merge -
```

They also run from a different tty so you need to

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 xclock
```