# Error: Can't open display: (null) after some time

Tags: xorg

Each time after a certain amount of time, any attempt to run a graphical program is causing the error "Can't open display".

For example:

```
[shhdup@localhost ~]$ LANG=C xterm 
No protocol specified
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0

[shhdup@localhost ~]$ LANG=C xdotool getactivindiw
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Some system info:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.6-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 13 09:47:01 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
i3 version 4.6 (2013-08-07, branch "tags/4.6") © 2009-2013 Michael 

Stapelberg and contributors
X.Org X Server 1.14.2
Release Date: 2013-06-25
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.9.7-1-ARCH x86_64 
Current Operating System: Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.6-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 13 09:47:01 CEST 2013 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=3bca1b94-7f18-4ec7-a589-e50f295db4fc rw quiet
Build Date: 01 July 2013  10:48:42AM

Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of x11-forwarding (e.g. `ssh -X`)?

Comment: No, as far as I know, I just use `startx` on my local machine.

Comment: Anything in your logs? (`/var/log/Xorg*` or other logs in there?)

Comment: May be Xauth is enabled in your Xserver even for local users like in: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/276357? Also, see http://www.softpanorama.org/Xwindows/Troubleshooting/can_not_open_display.shtml

Comment: Looks like your [X cookie file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126) is disappearing somewhere. What distribution are you running? What session manager, desktop environment or window manager? what is the value of the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable? This is the name of a file (if the variable isn't set, `~/.Xauthority` is used); what filesystem is it on?