# Running GUI application as another (non-root) user

Tags: shell, x11, xorg, su

Let's say I have 2 user accounts `user1` and `user2`. When I login as `user1`, and then switch to `user2` using `su`, I can execute command-line programs, but GUI programs fail.

Example:

```
user1@laptop:~$ su - user2
user2@laptop:~$ leafpad ~/somefile.txt
No protocol specified
leafpad: Cannot open display:
```

So how can I run a GUI application?

Comment: One of the main reasons, I've found, that this fails is because `$XAUTHORITY` is still set to user1's `~/.Xauthority`, which the program, I guess, will try to read, and it fails because that file typically has mode 0600 (`-rw-------`), meaning it's unavailable for reading by anyone in the "other" group, which includes user2. Meaning if you `chmod o+r ~/.Xauthority` (as user1), you will have hacked your way around this problem. I wrote a [script](https://pastebin.com/G9eJc8DK) that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### su vs. su -

When becoming another user you generally want to use `su - user2`. The dash will force user2's `.bash_profile` to get sourced.

#### xhost

Additionally you'll need to grant users access to your display. This is governed by X. You can use the command `xhost +` to allow other users permission to display GUI's to user1's desktop.

**NOTE:** When running `xhost +` you'll want to run this while still in a shell that belongs to user1.

#### $DISPLAY

When you become user2 you may need to set the environment variable `$DISPLAY`.

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Comment: When should I execute `xhost +user2`? From `user1` context or from `user2` context? Both gave me an error - `xhost:  bad hostname "user2"` when executing from `user1`, and `No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0"` when executed from `user2`.

Comment: Btw I updated my question, you can remove the part about `su - user2` now.

Comment: @satuon - OK, I'm going to leave it in the answer so that other people that may come across this Q&A in the future understand that that needs to be explicitly done. See updates.

Comment: `xhost +user2` still gives me this error - `xhost: bad hostname "user2"`. I googled some, and it seems I need to do `xhost +user2@laptop` or `xhost +user2@localhost`, not sure which. Then it says `xhost +user2@localhost being added to access control list`.

Comment: But even after adding the user with `xhost`, and specifying `export DISPLAY=:0.0`, running `leafpad` still gives me `No protocol specified leafpad: Cannot open display:`, and fails to run. I found this link at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/xlib-connection-to-0-0-refused-by-server-xlib-no-protocol-specified-152556/, which says that there are some magic cookies and `xauth`. Have you tested that those things work on your computer btw? Maybe something's different with my configuration? I'm on Debian+LXDE.

Comment: @satuon - instead of `xhost +user2` try `xhost +` to allow anyone, just to see if that works. When in user1's desktop, in a shell type `echo $DISPLAY`, and confirm that they're on `:0.0`.

Comment: Thanks, `xhost +` works, and nothing else seems to be needed (no need to set `$DISPLAY`). Can you update your answer, and I'll accept it?

Comment: @satuon - updated.

Comment: @slm - is it possible to specify a user at all? Each time is gives a error about a bad hostname - I also tried various incantations of `xhost +guest@127.0.0.1` and those didn't work (the output said the user had been added to the access control list though... - I am trying to test something under a different user without logging out :) `xhost +` does work on Fedora 21 though, and I ran `xhost -` after I finished as I think it returns it to normal.

Comment: Oh, found something. On Fedora 21 running `xhost` gives a list in the format `SI:localuser:USERNAME`, so `xhost SI:localuser:user2` should work. Oh and the display of the user can be found using `w`.

Comment: Also described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26054/52956)

Comment: I didn't understand the commands but it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: `xhost +` will allow any user on any host that can connect to your x-server to access your screen. `xhost +SI:localuser:user2` works for me on Debian.

Comment: It's interesting to note that the only reason `su` ing to another user and executing a GUI program from that shell doesn't work is because `$XAUTHORITY` is set to user1's `.Xauthority`, which cannot normally be read by user2. Thus, running `chmod o+r ~/.Xauthority` as user1 and then running `XAUTHORITY=/home/<user1>/.Xauthority DISPLAY=<display> <program>` as user2 is a quick hack-y way to get around this. Even without any form of `xhost +`, from my experiments. Thus, I wrote a [convenient script](https://pastebin.com/G9eJc8DK).

Comment: I am running Debian "testing" with Xfce. In the past, `xhost +` was enough, but now I realize that I must manually set and export `$DISPLAY`. Does anybody know why?

Comment: More xhost details and options (debian based solydX):
This will allow any local user to access the display:
`xhost +local:`

From the man page: "The  local family specifies all the local connections at once. However, the server interpreted address "si:localuser:username" can be  used  to specify a single local user"

So this worked for me:
`xhost +si:localuser:[username]`

Answer (score 17):

You could use X11 forwarding:

```
ssh -XY otheruser@localhost your-gui-program-name-here
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. The simplest I 've read so far. Far more people are familiar with ssh than with x11 configuration.

Answer (score 11):

You need to share the authentication token from the *user1* (assuming `~`is home of *user1*):

```
cat ~/.Xauthority | sudo -u user2 -i tee .Xauthority > /dev/null
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me (Ubuntu 14).

Comment: This solution works nicely from within the remote machine (= X Win client) while the xhost solutions in other answers have to be executed on the local machine (= X Win server).

Comment: It might be safer to use `tee -a` to avoid clobbering any existing information in `.Xauthority`.

Answer (score 10):

You can start app from another user. I will start the gimp app from user2, while being logged in (GUI) with user 1:

```
$ xhost +
$ sudo su user2
```

(enter pass)

```
$ gimp
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: can you tell a quick better way?

Comment: I've always used this method, but it's no longer working to me with Debian and Xfce. (*correction*: it does work, but I have to `export DISPLAY` first, as the accepted answer says)

Comment: after you end your session it will be good to disable it by `$ xhost -`

Answer (score 4):

You may try the sux command:

```
sux user2
```

sux will handle the $DISPLAY stuff for you.
You may need to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install sux
```

under Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: `sux` is no longer shipped by Debian or Ubuntu. The best alternative I could find is adding `xhost SI:localuser:root` (or whatever user) to `~/.xprofile` to allow it permanently or to use `runuser`

Comment: Up to and including Debian Stretch, there was `gksu` / `gksudo` alternative that worked fine. While still in Sid, it is removed in Buster for security issues.

Answer (score 3):

As alternative to `sux`, to safely run graphical command (`firefox-esr` in example below) as `$AUTHUSER` (`guest` in example below):

```
AUTHUSER=guest
AUTHSTRING=SI:localuser:${AUTHUSER}
xhost +${AUTHSTRING} > /dev/null
SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass
export SUDO_ASKPASS
sudo -k --askpass -u ${AUTHUSER} /usr/bin/firefox-esr
xhost -${AUTHSTRING} > /dev/null
sudo -K
```

the code does:

1. gives the `guest` user access to your current user `$DISPLAY` via `xhost +SI:localuser:guest`
2. uses `ssh-askpass` to graphically ask you for password (of course, you could use `sudoers(5)` `NOPASSWD:` to avoid this, if your security policy thinks it is ok. Or you could use other `askpass` programs, or specify them in config files (see `sudo(8)` for details on `--askpass`)
3. if the password is ok (and you have permissions in `sudoers(5)`) it runs the command `/usr/bin/firefox-esr` as another user (`guest`)
4. after the program completes, permissions to other user (`guest`) to access your `$DISPLAY` are revoked via `xhost -SI:localuser:guest`
5. finally, `sudo -K` removes cached password, so next invocation of `ssh-askpass` will ask you for password again (instead of using cached password)

   while it is little more work than what `gksu(8)` or `sux(8)` did, it can be scripted, and it is much more secure than:

   - `xhost +` (any user will have access to your graphical display as long as it is in effect)
   - readable ~/.xauth by other users (indefinite access by that user to your display)
   - what `gksu`/`sux` did (temporary copy of `~/.Xauthority`, which allowed specified user to copy your `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` and continue using your display even after gksu/sux finished (as long as you did not shutdown machine or logged out of display - screensavers, hibernate etc did not change the magic cookie).

as it will allow only one local user access to your display, and then only as long as the command runs (when command finishes, `$AUTHUSER` will no longer be able to access your display in any way).

Another safe alternative is  `ssh -X` (without `-Y` which actually makes you less secure! see `ForwardX11Trusted` in `ssh_config(5)` for details), as is easier to use if you are not scripting it, but it induces additinal overhead (eg. it is slower) and some programs might not work correctly without **unsafe** `-Y`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pkexec`, from `man pkexec`:

> DESCRIPTION 
> pkexec allows an authorized user to execute PROGRAM as another user. If
> username is not specified, then the program will be executed as the
> administrative super user, root.

First you need to give to that user the permission with `xhost`, to use the GUI.

To add an user permanently you can add the following `xhost` command to `/etc/bash.bashrc` (system wide) or locally in `~/.bashrc`.
On debian.

You can use this script to launch leafpad as user2:

```
#!/bin/sh

xhost SI:localuser:user2
pkexec --user user2 env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY leafpad
```

Comment: you can also add access to $XAUTHORITY file

`~ > chgrp developer $XAUTHORITY `
`~ > chmod g+r $XAUTHORITY   `
If both users are in same group `developer`

Answer (score 3):

Most solutions provided here don't integrate with Wayland and PulseAudio.

I wrote `ego` (Alter Ego), which automatically handles `xhost` and Wayland and PulseAudio socket sharing: https://github.com/intgr/ego

So you just run `ego leafpad` or `ego -u user2 leafpad`

If you run into problems, please open an issue on GitHub. I may be the only user of it, so it hasn't gotten much testing yet.

Answer (score -2):

You need to load installation UI as **user2**.

Try to following this:

Login as **root**:

```
sudo su
```

Test the x server:

```
xclock
```

If you can see a clock running, that's good to go, now try run this:

```
xhost
```

The result should like this:

```
xhost SI:localuser:tri
# tri is my user name
```

Now let **user2** access xhost

```
xhost +SI:localuser:user2
```

now try to login again to **user2** and try to open any of GUI program.

Comment: (1) There is nothing in this question that requires running as root, or where running as root is beneficial. (1b) If anything, running as root may just confuse matters. (2) There’s rarely (if ever) any reason to use `sudo su`.  Use `sudo` or `su`; pick one. (3) The question is written in terms of `user1` and `user2`.  Please write your answer in terms of `user1` and `user2`.  (Do or do not; there is no `tri`.) (4) Your answer would be better if it included an explanation of `SI:localuser`. … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.