# Cannot open X server on local machine

Tags: centos, x11, x-server

I'm trying to open GUI installation from shell without success so I tried first to open just `xclock` but was unable as well. usually export to DISPLAY solved the problem. I have a haunch that it security related but I lack the right knowledge to debug it.

```
[grid@localhost grid122]$ export DISPLAY=:0
[grid@localhost grid122]$ xclock 
No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0
[grid@localhost grid122]$ export DISPLAY=localhost:0
[grid@localhost grid122]$ xclock 
Error: Can't open display: localhost:0
```

Tried different addresses as well:

```
localhost:0.0
127.0.0.1:0
127.0.0.1:0.0
```

Also modify `/etc/hosts.allow` didn't work.

I am using CentOS 7 with GNOME

Comment: are you logged in as the same user as the one who opened the GUI / Gnome?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126

Comment: it is different user than the one I logged in. I'll check the authority you send and report back

Answer (score -1):

Answer [found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108784/running-gui-application-as-another-non-root-user) here once I understand the problem - I can start `xclock` from the user I logged in but not from other users.
Solution was running `xhost +` from the user I logged into.

Funny thing is I did `xhost +` numerous times before.

Comment: That's a terrible solution unless you are absolutely totally sure your X Server can't be accessed remotely (directly on port 6000 or indirectly by someone logging in to your machine remotely).