# Cannot connect to X server :0.0 as superuser

Tags: x11, su, xauth

When I am online, I get following error and the tool does not start:

```
[root@dhcppc9 lin64]# ./ise
No protocol specified
_pn: cannot connect to X server :0.0
```

But everything is OK when I am not a superuser. Why that?

**Edit**

```
[root@dhcppc9 lin64]# export $(dbus-launch)
No protocol specified
```

any suggestion?

**Also**

```
[root@dhcppc9 lin64]# xhost [+]
No protocol specified
xhost:  unable to open display ":0.0"
```

Comment: This is a classic. You may do `export $(dbus-launch)` or use `xhost [+]` to be able to launch programs using X and your superuser account.

Comment: Did both , see the edit above

Comment: It may be `$ xhost` to see the current access and `$ xhost +` to enable access from any host. You often do this from a virtual terminal you know for sure that can spawn programs using X.

Comment: @galegosimpatico: why would launching a dbus server solve this issue?

Comment: When you are not superuser, what does `echo $DISPLAY` show? Which user does the xserver process, you want to use, belong to? (you can find out the latter by using for example `ps faux`)

Comment: @Bananguin The dbus relaunch from a terminal works around X connection problems in some versions of Debian. But it's true that this users' prompt hints the use of a non Debian family GNU/Linux distribution (maybe Fedora?).

Comment: @Bananguin: i am getting :0.0, when i give echo $DISPLAY

Comment: @Bananguin: but i could not understand second part of your question.

Comment: IIRC, `xhost` should be run from inside the X server as the user who is running the X session. Is that root as well?

Comment: Using `xhost +` is the equivalent of "opening a huge security hole big enough for anyone to drive a bus through".

Comment: @galegosimpatico No, neither of these will help. (`xhost +` might on some setups, but if it does, you don't want to use it: it means “allow anybody to do anything with my account”.)

Comment: Oh yeah, running `xhost +` exposes root and user login passwords as long as samba passwords. And God kills 314 kittens too.

Answer (score 16):

An X program needs two pieces of information in order to connect to an X display.

- It needs the address of the display, which is typically `:0` when you're logged in locally or `:10`, `:11`, etc. when you're logged in remotely (but the number can change depending on how many X connections are active). The address of the display is normally indicated in the `DISPLAY` environment variable.
- It needs the password for the display. X display passwords are called *magic cookies*. Magic cookies are not specified directly: they are always stored in X authority files, which are a collection of records of the form “display `:42` has cookie `123456`”. The X authority file is normally indicated in the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable. If `$XAUTHORITY` is not set, programs use `~/.Xauthority`.

See [Open a window on a remote X display (why "Cannot open display")?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126) for more details.

In your case, `DISPLAY` is set but programs evidently cannot find the cookie file. Check the value of `XAUTHORITY` in your session and under `su`.

If `XAUTHORITY` is not set in your session and `su` sets the `HOME` environment variable to root's home directory, then you need to set `XAUTHORITY` to `/home/msz/.Xauthority` where `/home/msz` is your home directory.

If `su` removes `XAUTHORITY` from the environment, either put it back, or configure `su` not to do this.

If your home directory is on some filesystems like NFS, root may not be able to read it directly. In that case, you can copy the `.Xauthority` file to a different location on a non-NFS filesystem:

```
XAUTHORITY_COPY=$(umask 077; mktemp)
cat "${XAUTHORITY:-~/.Xauthority}" "$XAUTHORITY_COPY"
XAUTHORITY="$XAUTHORITY_COPY" su
rm "$XAUTHORITY_COPY"
unset XAUTHORITY_COPY
```

Comment: I created a symbolic link and it worked as well. Here it is: `ln -s /home/otheruser/.Xauthority ~`

Comment: XAUTHORITY for me was set as a file that no longer existed:

Answer (score 6):

You are running xhost as root !

run xhost as the normal user `xhost +` , then become root then try again.

btw as others have pointed out `xhost +` permits any user from any host

Comment: Many modern systems are set up so that `xhost` does not work. If it does, then at least run `xhost +localhost`, not `xhost +`!

Comment: Understand, that's a good point. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It was my problem! Thank you, it solved everything! I simply ran it from non-root.

Answer (score 1):

XAUTHORITY for me was set as a file that no longer existed:

`$ echo $XAUTHORITY`

`/tmp/xauth-1000-_0`

So I did

`unset XAUTHORITY`

and was then able to connect to my app as root using kdesudo (in this case `kdesudo bleachbit`)

Answer (score 0):

Run as normal user

```
xhost + localhost
```

then enable super user by

```
sudo su
```

finally go to server example

```
cd /usr/local/Ampps
```

finally run 
    ./Ampps

thank me in 2020

Answer (score 0):

[This worked for me in fedora 30](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2375827)

```
xhost local:root
sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 /usr/bin/unetbootin
```