# unable to open X server

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to display the dimensions of an image and then resize them with a program my system says is there called `Package ImageMagick-6.5.4.7-7.el6_5.i686 already installed and latest version`.

But getting error:

> -bash-4.1# display main-bg1.jpg
>
> display: unable to open X server `' @ display.c/DisplayImageCommand/420.

Comment: Layz man's answer: just download `MobaXterm` and problem solved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That message is because you do not have permissions from that shell (root) to display GUI windows to the X server that I presume is running as your normal user.

In another window as your normal user:

```
$ xhost +
```

Then try it again. If it still does not work then you can try explicitly setting the `$DISPLAY` variable in root's shell:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Then repeat your command, `display ...`.

#### I've logged into a remote server via SSH

If you've logged into some distant server using something like `ssh root@remote` you'll likely get something like this:

```
$ ssh -x root@skinner xeyes
Error: Can't open display: 
$
```

Now if you use the switch `-X`:

[image: ss of xeyes]

You should get the GUI app remotely displayed back to you.

Comment: sorry I'm not following you. I am running the command as root...

Comment: I tried export DISPLAY=:0.0
 but it has made no difference.

Comment: @cea - your desktop is not owned by root, it's some other user that you logged in with. That user owns the X server and you need to grant anyone access to it, `xhost +`.

Comment: still confused because there is no desktop as such, only my remote server where linux is installed...so do I need to find the program and change the ownership?

Comment: @cea - nope. Can you update your Q, you're logged into a remote server? The situation is important to understanding how to fix it.

Comment: sorry update my which?

Comment: @cea - for example, can we assume that you used `ssh root@remoteserver` to get into that system?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: So then you'll likely need to allow X traffic to come back over your SSH tunnel. Try `ssh -X root@remote`.

Comment: you mean logout and log back in as such?

Comment: @cea - correct.

Comment: Oh! that has opened it ON my desktop. What is going on here? I am new to this completely.

Comment: still says cannot connect?

Comment: @cea - OK one more time. Exit that connection and now try this. (1) `xhost +` (2) `ssh -X root@remote` (3) `display ...`.

Comment: I did all of the above but still says cannot connect even though I can plainly see the server in my desktop window, are you saying I need to now re login the normal way?

Comment: NEVERMIND! I will have to go and read about this. Sorry and I will just assume you have the answer correct as I'm sure you do.

Comment: @cea - take a look at these 2 Q&A's they cover everything you're asking about: [Open a window on a remote X display (why “Cannot open display”)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126) & [Cannot connect to X server :0.0 as superuser](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111831/cannot-connect-to-x-server-0-0-as-superuser)

Comment: @cea - getting the remote display working can be one of the trickier things to get initially. Look over those 2 links and if you're still stuck I'll be around and can try and give you more detailed help. I'm bumping into my bed time now. 8-)

Comment: WAIT it has opened another window!!! called xterm but that says display command not found

Comment: Ok this might take me a while to work out because it is not opening in my terminal but it an application type terminal- all VERY weird but interesting! thanks :) I will try to work it out.

Comment: @cea - I'll be around if you need more help.

Comment: @slm: I know this is old news, but I’m puzzled by the order of your first few paragraphs.   (1) The error message in the question appears to be complaining that `$DISPLAY` is not set (`display: unable to open X server ‘’`), so setting `DISPLAY` should be the first thing you try.  Also, (2) if `$DISPLAY` is not set correctly, running `xhost` won’t help — so, again, ensuring that `$DISPLAY` is set correctly should be the first step, in general.

Comment: @G-Man - probably b/c I wrote that A'er at 4am in the morning 8-). Yeah the advice about `xhost +` was essentially unnecessary in this particular situation. I generally give this advice as a package and have become immune to the actual order one gets the messages in. The 2 fundamental problems w/ remote displaying one will run into are (1) Xserver running locally does not have permissions to receive incoming connections (`xhost +`), and (2) the remote server is not configured to properly send data to me.