# xsel not recognized after "su - other-account"

Tags: x11, su

I am new to Linux and have set up the following version of Ubuntu as a VirtualBox VM using [this process](https://linuxiac.com/ubuntu-with-virtualbox):

```
ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

The first account created was a administrator account.  I installed `xsel` and checked that it worked.  I then created a non-administrator account and `su`d into it with `su - non-admin-account`.  At that point, `xsel` complains:

```
xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

**What do I have to do to make `xsel` accessible after `su`ing into another account?**

Presently, I'm not interested in starting apps that launch their own client windows when `su`'d into the non-administrator account.  I just want simple piping of *standard out* to the clipboard so that I can retrieve it in Vim or the Bash command line using Shift+Ins, e.g., `echo dog | xsel -ib` or `echo dog | xsel -ip`.

My current plan is to write or redirect to (say) `/tmp/tmp.txt` to pass text between a user that logged in from a login screen versus one that was `su`d to.  I'm used to Cygwin's behaviour, where the clipboard is shared regardless of which account a terminal is started under.

---

**Troubleshooting**

I get the same behaviour if I log into the non-administrator account and `su` to the administrator account.  `xsel` works in the non-administrator that I log into, but not the administrator account that I `su` to.

**Essentially, `xsel` doesn't work after an `su`.**

**As per the comments, I looked at [this problem's answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111831/cannot-connect-to-x-server-0-0-as-superuser).**  I don't recognize the problem description, as the error messages are quite different, so someone looking based on error messages won't recognize that question.  Furthermore, I don't understand the answers.  The bit that looked like it might apply to my solution was `xhost +localhost`, but it didn't work because the syntax is wrong, at least for the Ubuntu version I'm using.  I post the syntax that *does* work in my answer below.

I think that before that above cited page can even remotely inform someone, you have to know that the problem is the lack of permission for an account to access the X server.  For example, if you come from a background of using Cygwin's X-windows, you would probably not guess this because the problem doesn't manifest itself there.

Comment: Read `man xhost`, and do something like `xhost +localhost` before the `su`. That will open up the "display" to every user on `localhost`.

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/965085/767015), I tried `xhost +SI:localuser:nonadmin-username`, which yielded `localuser:nonadmin-username being added to access control list`.  I then issued `su - nonadmin-username` and `ls | xsel -ip` and `ls | xsel -ib`, but I get the same error as above. I need to read and experiment more. As per the linked page, issuing `xhost` from the admin account yields `SI:localuser:nonadmin-username` and `SI:localuser:admin-username`.

Comment: SOLVED. After `su`ing to nonadmin-username, I issued `export DISPLAY=:0` to match the variable's value in the admin account. Then `ls | xsel -ip` didn't generate any messages (good), suggesting that the text was sent to the "PRIMARY selection" buffer.  I then exitted from the `su` session and issued `cat` from the admin account so that I can paste the text via Shift+Ins (emulates X11 middle-mouse-button click).  It behaved as expected.  **Thanks!**  Did you want to post the answer?

Comment: You contradict yourself - you say "_I'm not interested in starting X [...] applications when su'd into the non-administrator account_" and then whinge that you can't start `xsel` which is an X11 application.  What do you actually want?

Comment: @Toby Speight: I clarified that phrase.  I also saw that someone referred to [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111831/cannot-connect-to-x-server-0-0-as-superuser).  In the troubleshooting section, I explain why I don't think that will help someone who is looking for the symptoms that I saw.  Before that page can help, you have to know that the problem is the lack of permission for an account to access the X server.

Comment: "so someone looking based on error messages won't recognize that question." ... that's one of the points having questions closed as duplicates - people searching for variants of the same problem can arrive at the dupe.

Comment: People who aren't familiar with the underlying cause will search based on the error message that they see.  As well, I found the description of the cited question to be unrecognizable. Finally, the xhost syntax I provide below differs from what is posted in the cited question. I don't know why, just that the syntax in the cited question doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on *waltinator*'s comment, I found [this page](https://superuser.com/a/965085/767015) on using `xhost`.  From that information, I found the following to work:

```
# Log into admin-username from the login screen,
# then issue:
$ xhost +SI:localuser:nonadmin-username

   localuser:nonadmin-username being added to access control
   list.

$ xhost

   SI:localuser:nonadmin-username
   SI:localuser:admin-username

$ su - nonadmin-username
# Enter password when prompted

# Match DISPLAY to its value in the admin account
$ export DISPLAY=:0

$ ls | xsel -ip # Use PRIMARY selection e.g. X-windows mouse highlighting
$ ls | xsel -ib # Use CLIPBOARD buffer e.g. Windows's Ctrl+C/X/V
$ exit # Exit the "su" session

# Paste then works in admin account as expected.
# To test the PRIMARY selection:
$ cat # In admin account
# Paste using middle mouse button or Shift+Ins
Ctrl+D to end input into "cat"
```

A useful alternative to adding users one-at-a-time is `xhost +local:`, which allows any local user to open client windows.  This implies that you trust everybody logged on to the machine.  Therefore, this should only be done in controlled environments, such as single-user machines.

In many environments, the PRIMARY selection can also be pasted in [G]Vim from register `*`.

Similarly, the CLIPBOARD buffer can often be pasted in [G]Vim from register `+`, or from any other app that uses Ctrl+V.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`pam_xauth`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_xauth) authentication module to forward X11 session cookies across `su` invocations, without opening up your X server to those users more generally.

This also allows fine-grained control over which users can forward credentials to which other users, via config files in their `$HOME/.xauth/` directories.

Comment: Thanks, Toby Speight.  Being a newbie to Linux, I've never heard of "die.net", but it seems to have been [popular](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/4ncmlm/who_runs_dienet) even 5 years ago.  I'm glad that the `pam_xauth` page provides examples, as I found the `xauth` man pages to presume a lot of knowledge of how X-windows operates.  I was surprised that xhost wasn't mentioned, though I'm far from well versed with X-windows under the hood. I'm also glad that there is a [Wikipedia background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization) page on `xauth`.

Comment: Yes, the examples are really helpful, and make that man page a good example.