# remote X display cannot open

Tags: x11

I am connecting from Windows with Putty and [XLaunch](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/IDH_DISPLAY.htm) to a Debian machine version 7.6, I have tried it on other machines and it worked, the problem is the Debian machine itself, not the configuration.
I have already tried this:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
xhost localhost
```

The last command tells me that it is unable to open a display.

**NOTE:** I'm on a Windows system attempting to use XLaunch to remote display an X application from the Debian system, to Windows.

Comment: Open a shell on the Debian machine and issue the command `echo $DISPLAY` and report its output.

Comment: This is the result :0.0DISPLAY=:0.0

Comment: First of all, where do you issue `xhost localhost` on the server or on you local machine. If the former try the latter. And if the latter: (Although you should not do this in terms of a long term soltion. And here only done for debugging purposes.) What happens, when you enter `xhost +` on your local machine thereby granting access to any user.

Comment: The problem is the machine I connect remotetly

Comment: What if you try `set DISPLAY=put-in-you-ip-here` and then `export DISPLAY` on the remote machine? That helped me with Putty.

Comment: Do you want to display X11 applications on the Windows machine, or on the remote Debian machine? If you want to display things on Windows, do not set `DISPLAY`: if it isn't set, then forwarding is not in place and setting `DISPLAY` cannot help; the problem is probably in the PuTTY configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my configuration :

**Xlauch**

- in first screen, there is a field called Display number, do not use 0, try 1756 (for instance), next
- next (Start no client)
- check 'no access control', next
- done

**Putty**

- in Connection -> SSH -> X11 :

  - enable X11 forwarding
  - X Display Location : put `localhost:1756.0`
- connect, do not set DISPLAY in any .bashrc et all.

when connected launch any X client.

Comment: Do you know what does the ".0" in localhost:1756.0" mean?

Comment: Also how does the "no access control" help in setting up a reliable and repeatable connection with Xming?

Comment: I always use 0, I guess .1, .2 are in case you have multiple screen. I use "no access control" because I was unable to set a proper access control.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. when you  mean multiple screens do you mean multiple screens on the server to which you are trying to login?

Comment: For me, it turns out that using localhost:1757.0 (in putty) and 1756  (as Display Number in Xlaunch) works the same as using  0.0 (in putty) and 0 (as Display Number in Xlaunch). In either case when I login to the remote server "echo $DISPLAY" reads "localhost:10.0".

Comment: When I have multiple windows open, the DISPLAY value increments by 1, so $DISPLAY increases from "localhost:10" to "localhost:11", similar to the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display