# How to launch xev from console?

Tags: x11, sudo, console

I am trying to launch Xev from console, it always gives "unable to open display", I need to launch xev from a console as another user (I use **sudo -u '#1000'** to do this).

I know xev has a "display" argument (**xev -display**) but I just can't figure out how to use it.

How do I launch xev from the console from outside of my X11 environment?

Comment: For all X11 programs there is an environment variable `DISPLAY`. For Display `0` you can do `DISPLAY=:0 xev`. Now you will get an error about security X11 has security to stop you doing this. You need to look into `xauth`. Note `xhost +` is dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All¹ X11 programs open their windows on the display indicated by the environment variable `DISPLAY`. Thus:

```
sudo -u 1000 env DISPLAY=:0 xev
```

or for that matter, since you can run programs as a different user from the X server, just

```
DISPLAY=:0 xev
```

`:NUMBER` is the notation for local displays; in most scenarios, the X11 server that is running on the console is the one that's started first and ends up being number 0. You can run `echo "$DISPLAY"` in a terminal on that display to check whether the display number is correct. `:0.0` is equivalent to `:0` (a trailing `.0` can be omitted).

If you run the program as a different user from the X server, and sometimes even if you run it as the same user, you may need to set the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable as well. This variable points to a file that contains a password (called a *cookie*) that applications must pass to the X server. To see the right value from `XAUTHORITY`, run `echo $XAUTHORITY` on that display; if it's unset, the default value is `~/.Xauthority` where `~` represents the user's home directory.

If you need to find the values of `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` programmatically, see [Open a window on a remote X display (why "Cannot open display")?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126)

¹  <sub>At least almost all. It's technically possible for them not to, but it takes active work on the part of the programmer to make it not so, whereas a `-display` argument is a convention that is far from universal.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! This worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
xev --display localhost:0.0
```

assuming that X is actually running.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @Cestarian Have you checked that X is actually running?

Comment: Yes of course, it's running on tty 1.

Comment: @Cestarian Maybe you can include some more information in your question, like how started `X` and other things that might seem relevant. As the other user did you run `xhost +` to actually allow access to the X server?

Comment: I started X with the startx command. I did not even have xhost installed. Naturally I am not familiar with how to operate it either.

Answer (score -1):

The following command is very useful:

```
xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'
```

But you need to set DISPLAY variable and it's related to your position to xev machine.

**NOTE:** When you apply DISPALY variable that your position is illlegal, or you don't have any local access to machine.