# udev monitor hotplug rule not running

Tags: monitoring, udev, monitors, hot-plug

I have setup a basic udev rule to detect when I connect or disconnect a mDP cable.

The file is `/etc/udev/rules.d/95-monitor-hotplug.rules`

```
KERNEL=="card0", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/var/run/gdm/auth-for-vazquez-OlbTje/database", RUN+="/usr/bin/arandr"
```

It should just launch arandr when their is a mDP cable connected or disconnected, but nothing happens. I have also reloaded the rules with:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
This is how the problem was solved. With the links provided by @Gilles. I added the following code to my `.profile` then pointed the `ENV{$XAUTHORITY}="/home/user/.Xauthority"` and also added `ACTION=="change"` to the rules file. After that everything was working as it should. Thanks Gilles.

```
case $DISPLAY:$XAUTHORITY in
  :*:?*)
    # DISPLAY is set and points to a local display, and XAUTHORITY is
    # set, so merge the contents of `$XAUTHORITY` into ~/.Xauthority.
    XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority xauth merge "$XAUTHORITY";;
esac
```

Comment: Try to debug with `sudo udevmonitor -e` or watching `/var/log/udev`

Comment: I don't have udevmonitor and is their anything I should be grepping for in /var/log/udev/?  I see all the usual output from connecting and disconnecting the mDP cable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An udev rule applies to the `add` action by default. The udev rule is on a graphics card, not on a monitor; so it runs when a graphics card is added to the system, which in practice means at boot time.

Plugging in a monitor results in a `change` action, not an `add` action. You can observe this by running `udevadm monitor` and plugging a monitor in. So the udev rule should specify a `change` action.

```
KERNEL=="card0", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", \
    ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/var/run/gdm/auth-for-vazquez-OlbTje/database", RUN+="/usr/bin/arandr"
```

Examples found on the web corroborate my understanding, e.g. [codingtony](https://github.com/codingtony/udev-monitor-hotplug/blob/master/etc/udev/rules.d/99-monitor-hotplug.rules) whose [`monitor-hotplug.sh` script](https://github.com/codingtony/udev-monitor-hotplug/blob/master/usr/local/bin/monitor-hotplug.sh) may be of interest to you.

The file name under `/var/run` changes each time you reboot, so you should determine it automatically inside your script. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126) should help.

Comment: Should `ACTION=''change"` be `ACTION=`**=**`"change"` --> added another **=**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone dealing with nvidia card, to make udev rule work, you will have to turn on the kernel mode setting

```
sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args='nvidia-drm.modeset=1'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/459700)