# Pop up a message on the GUI from cron

Tags: x11, notifications

In KDE, I find that if I echo something to `pts/0`:

```
me@mypc:~$ echo hello > /dev/pts/0
```

I get a message flash sent to myself.

I'd like to make a cron job to send similar messages to myself regularly. How can I do this?

P.S. I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> switches to the GUI, but `echo`ing to `/dev/tty7` just gives me a `permission denied` error.

Comment: If you can think of a better title, feel free to change it.

Comment: @Thomas `notify-send` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to send a pop up message to a user logged into a Desktop Environment, have a look at `notify-send`.

Comment: And see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display about accessing X11 from cron.

Answer (score 2):

xmessage is another way to spawn a window with text, which can work without notification daemons and can also have buttons.

Might be useful to someone, despite the facts it:

- is ugly;
- will spawn a tiling window in tiling window managers (I was actually searching for a way to fix that when I found this question);
- does not work on wayland (obviously);

Comment: xmessage may be ugly, but unlike notify-send, it works from cron without messing about with environment variables, etc. It also runs on both Macs and Linux with zero hassle. It gets my vote!

Comment: Correction: it turns out that if you run xmessage in a script called by cron, you DO have to put "export DISPLAY=:0" at the top of the script, but apart from that, xmessage is hassle-free.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the `write` command? This command allows you to send a message to a given user, which is then printed on his terminal/console. You can optionally specify the tty to send the message to.

Comment: I know `write` already. I'm looking for a GUI alternative.