# Cronjob executes `/usr/bin/python` but not `usr/bin/xrdb`

Tags: shell-script, cron

I'm trying to create my first cron job. I'm new to bash scripting too, although I do know some python. I am puzzled by the following:

Here is my cronjob file created with `crontab -e`:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/darren/.bash_scripts/urxvt_colors.sh
```

Contents of `urxvt_colors.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

python  ~/.Py_Scripts/xr_random_colors.py
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

Here is what baffles me. So the python part of the cron job works `python  ~/.Py_Scripts/xr_random_colors.py` is executed every minute. This python script changes the color scheme in my `~/.Xresources` file. I confirmed this actually happens by checking every minute. But `xrdb ~/.Xresources` does not update the file.

Running `which python` shows `/usr/bin/python` and `which xrdb` shows `/usr/bin/xrdb`. So since they are both executed from `/usr/bin`, how come only the python script executes?

Also if I run `./urxvt_colors.sh` script manually from my terminal then it works as expected, the python script runs and so does `xrdb ~/.Xresources`

What's happening here?

Comment: Your cron job does not have the $DISPLAY and possibly $XAUTHORITY environment variables. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display

Comment: Try using a full path in place of `~/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

python  ~/.Py_Scripts/xr_random_colors.py && xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

and i recommend you to use full path to files.

PS maybe you need to define DISPLAY var while exec script

```
*/1 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /home/darren/.bash_scripts/urxvt_colors.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding `DISPLAY=:0` to the cronjob got things working. Reading the "This question already has an answer" link above explained to me why :)