# Bash script behaving differently when executed from Crontab: Edit - Environment Variable issues with Pulseaudio

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, pulseaudio

I have a script that executes perfectly fine manually, though two commands in particular are completely ignored by Cron (this is just a snippet):

```
sinkint=$(pacmd list-sinks | sed -n '/index\W [1-9]/p' | sed 's/.*://g;s/\W//g')

pacmd set-default sink $sinkint
pacmd set-sink-volume $sinkint 20%
```

Crontab

```
* * * * * /path/to/script arg1 >> /path/to/log
```

Error messages

```
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
You have to specify a sink name/index and a volume
```

Edit:

tried variables in script

```
export PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/pulse-socket
export PULSE_COOKIE=/tmp/pa_cookie
```

socket in my /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
load-module module-native-protocol-unix socket=/tmp/pulse-socket
```

socket and cookie in my /etc/pulse/client.conf

```
default-server = unix:/tmp/pulse-socket
cookie-file = /tmp/pa_cookie
```

crontab -e

```
PULSE_SERVER=unix:/tmp/pulse-socket
PULSE_COOKIE=/tmp/pa_cookie

* * * * * /path/to/script arg1 2> /path/to/log
```

Comment: You should have the output with the error on your user mail. Just be aware that usually Cron issues come from env variables that just aren't as you expect when the script runs. You might be missing something with the PATH variable.

Comment: If those error messages come from the commands in question, then they're not "completely ignored" by cron, but would seem to launched as desired, just with some other problem. It might be that `pacmd` needs some environment variables or such to find the server, at least the [Arch Linux wiki mentions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio#Environment_variables) `PULSE_SERVER` and `PULSE_COOKIE`. You may want to check that whatever it needs to find the daemon is available under cron, too.

Comment: If the environment variables you need are in your .profile, your answer may be [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `env | grep -i pulse` from a shell where the script works. You're probably missing an environment variable that is being set by pulseaudio in your session but not in the session run by cron.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378999/117549

Comment: @terdon that doesn't return anything

Comment: @ilkkachu that seems promising, do you suggest I add those environment variables straight into my crontab?

Comment: @user492155 that can't be. You have both `PULSE_SERVER` and `PULSE_COOKIE` there. Did you maybe run `grep` without the `-i`? Anyway, I would have suggested setting those two, and you did and it didn't help, so...

Comment: yeah, I checked all my environment variables and there's no pulse anywhere... lmao

Comment: either I got pulse audio set up wrong, or I have no idea what I'm doing with these variables haha

Comment: @user492155, I can't say, I don't pretty much anything about the internals of pulseaudio, or how it's commonly started. If it sets those variables somewhere/somehow when starting the server, they'd change at least on reboot etc. You'd need to have them stored in some file and have the crontab entry read that file to get them.

Comment: I got it working :D

Answer (score 3):

adding `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000` to crontab worked!

annoyingly... because it was literally the only enviroment variable that I needed. Oh well, if anybody needs the answer in the future - here it is I guess.

Answer (score -3):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: You've posted this answer to at least two questions, without changing it at all to reflect the specific question.  Taking into account that the issue was solved by the OP through setting `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, your answer reads more like a comment offering generic debugging help than an actual answer.

Comment: Since "My program doesn't work via `crontab`" questions appear far too frequently, I've tried to write a generic answer. It usually guides the user to the "right" answer. Can you suggest improvements?