# How to create a night mode with cron

Tags: linux-mint, cron

Am using Iris Mini to filter the blue light at night, it works pretty well but having to execute it manually is annoying. So am trying to use cron to start it each night at 8PM.

This is what i have written executing crontab -e. The command works if i execute it in the terminal

#### Crontab

```
0 20 * * * sh /home/jogarcia/Software/open-iris-mini.sh
```

#### open-iris-mini.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=0:.
/home/jogarcia/Software/iris-mini
```

I also executed `xhost +localhost`  for testing (before the  time of the cron tab).

Searching in the logs with `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` I found this lines that seems to suggest that is actually been executed:

#### cron log

```
Nov  2 20:00:01 my-computer-is-name CRON[8391]: (user) CMD (sh /home/jogarcia/Software/open-iris-mini.sh)
```

But it isn't working because i can't see the results on my screen (it should display a kind of orangish color) am really lost, I don't know what am doing wrong.

To see the errors I installed a mail service.

#### Local mail error

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 0:.
```

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret (as pointed out by @[waltinator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/11135/waltinator) is to set DISPLAY correctly.

That should probably be `DISPLAY=:0`

The format there is typically hostname:displaynumber, where hostname is optional.

The second issue is display security.
If you put the cronjob in your own crontab instead of root's, then `xhost` should not be needed as `xauth` will work.
OP has (probably) done this correctly by using `crontab -e` as himself.
(Note that `$HOME` must be correct for `xauth` security to work.  This is part of what putting it in your own crontab does.)

Another trick here is to install an email system to get the error messages.

When OP reported (after installing an email system) "that the cron job can't connect to the display", it probably means that either DISPLAY isn't right or something went wrong with display security (`xauth` and `xhost`).
To that, I advise to try running the script in a command window.
Try running it like `env -uDISPLAY /home/jose/Software/open-iris-mini.sh` (and if it says that file isn't executable, use `chmod +x`)

(answer added per request of OP.)

Answer (score 1):

This fails because `cron` jobs run in their own context, not the GUI context (where controlling colors "makes sense").

In order to get this to work, there are 2 steps

In your script, add a definition for the `DISPLAY` environment variable (used as a pointer to the X server). Something like

```
export DISPLAY=0:.
```

but check with `echo "$DISPLAY"` in your GUI context.

In your GUI startup (perhaps in `$HOME/.config/autostart`)

```
xhost +localhost
```

to tell the X server to accept connections originating from host `localhost` (or userid `localhost` -- X Windows security is wack). You have to do this EVERY GUI login.

Read `man xhost X`.

Comment: Am a Linux noob, i added what i think is your answer and still doesn't works. I updated my question would you check it?

Comment: That should probably be `DISPLAY=:0`  The format there is typically hostname:displaynumber, where hostname is optional.  If you put it in your own crontab instead of root's, then xhost should not be needed as xauth will work.  OP (@jogarcia) has (probably) done this correctly by using `crontab -e` as himself.  The other trick here is to install an email system to get the error messages.

Comment: @DavidG. I installed a mail service, now i can see the error logs, it simply says that the cron job can't connect to the display

Comment: @jogarcia That would typically mean either `DISPLAY` isn't set right, or display security prevents connection (`xauth` and `xhost`).  Try running your script in a command window.  Try running it like `env -uDISPLAY /home/jose/Software/open-iris-mini.sh`  (and if it says that file isn't executable, use `chmod +x`)

Comment: @DavidG. The file is running, though it's still throwing the error that it couldn't connect to the display

Comment: @DavidG. I got your command working

Comment: @DavidG. I got the cron job working, thanks bro. You should make your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what worked for me using the answers of both who answered before me

Use `crontab -e` for the cron job

```
MAILTO=somemail@mail.com
0 20 * * * sh /home/jogarcia/Software/open-iris-mini.sh
```

Then on the sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

DISPLAY=:0 /home/jogarcia/Software/iris-mini
```

To see if it was working as intended with the display i used the command:

```
env -uDISPLAY /home/jogarcia/Software/open-iris-mini.sh
```

To see the cron logs i installed postfix `sudo apt-get install postfix`, all local.