# Is there a command to list all open displays on a machine?

Tags: ssh, x-server

When SSH'd locally into my computer (don't ask, it's a workaround), I can't start graphical applications without running:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

If I run this first and then run a graphical application, things work out. If not, it doesn't work, there's no display to attach to.

Is there a command for listing all available displays (ie: all possible values) on a machine?

Comment: A cleaner way to launch applications from a terminal is `( DISPLAY=:0 yourapp & )`.

Comment: To get that display number from a command line script, try `w`. More info: [list existing X display names?](http://askubuntu.com/a/230838/398665)

Comment: "When SSH'd locally into my computer (don't ask, it's a workaround)"... made me giggle

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you want the X connection forwarded over SSH, you need to enable it on both the server side and the client side. (Depending on the distribution, it may be enabled or disabled by default.) On the server side, make sure that you have `X11Forwarding yes` in [`/etc/sshd_config`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5) (or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or wherever the configuration file is). On the client side, pass the `-X` option to the [`ssh` command](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1), or put `ForwardX11` in your [`~/.ssh/config`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5).

If you run `ssh -X localhost`, you should see that `$DISPLAY` is (probably) `localhost:10.0`. Contrast with `:0.0`, which is the value when you're not connected over SSH. (The `.0` part may be omitted; it's a screen number, but multiple screens are rarely used.) There are two forms of X displays that you're likely to ever encounter:

- Local displays, with nothing before the `:`.
- TCP displays, with a hostname before the `:`.

With `ssh -X localhost`, you can access the X server through both displays, but the applications will use a different method: `:NUMBER` accesses the server via local sockets and shared memory, whereas `HOSTNAME:NUMBER` accesses the server over TCP, which is slower and disables some extensions.

Note that you need a form of authorization to access an X server, called a cookie and normally stored behind the scenes in the file `~/.Xauthority`. If you're using ssh to access a different user account, or if your distribution puts the cookies in a different file, you may find that `DISPLAY=:0` doesn't work within the SSH session (but `ssh -X` will, if it's enabled in the server; you never need to mess with `XAUTHORITY` when doing `ssh -X`). If that's a problem, you need to [set the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/ssh-display-variable/10126#10126) or [obtain the other user's cookies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root/1600#1600).

To answer your actual question:

- Local displays correspond to a socket in `/tmp/.X11-unix`.

  ```
  (cd /tmp/.X11-unix && for x in X*; do echo ":${x#X}"; done)
  ```
- Remote displays correspond to open TCP ports above 6000; accessing display number N on machine M is done by connecting to TCP port 6000+N on machine M. From machine M itself:

  ```
  netstat -lnt | awk '
    sub(/.*:/,"",$4) && $4 >= 6000 && $4 < 6100 {
      print ($1 == "tcp6" ? "ip6-localhost:" : "localhost:") ($4 - 6000)
    }'
  ```

  (The rest of this bullet point is of academic interest only.)

  From another machine, you can use `nmap -p 6000-6099 host_name` to probe open TCP ports in the usual range. It's rare nowadays to have X servers listening on a TCP socket, especially outside the loopback interface.

  Strictly speaking, another application could be using a port in the range usually used by X servers. You can tell whether an X server is listening by checking which program has the port open.

  ```
  lsof -i -n | awk '$9 ~ /:60[0-9][0-9]$/ {print}'
  ```

  If that shows something ambiguous like `sshd`, there's no way to know for sure whether it's an X server or a coincidence.

Comment: The correlation between X11, ssh and display forwarding is further explained in a follow-up question to this answer: 
[What are X server, display and screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503806/238547)

Answer (score 28):

The display is the first argument to `Xorg`. You can `ps` then grep `Xorg` out.

```
[braga@coleman teste_geom]$ ps aux | grep Xorg
root      1584  5.3  1.0 156628 41708 tty1     Rs+  Jul22  22:56 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -background none -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-a3kSKB/database -nolisten tcp vt1
braga     9110  0.0  0.0 109104   804 pts/1    S+   00:26   0:00 grep --color=auto Xorg
```

You can then `awk` this into wherever format you need to.

Comment: This doesn't detect displays created by a server other than Xorg, e.g. [Xvnc](http://www.tigervnc.org/).

Comment: `ps aux |grep X` worked better for me

Comment: `w` shows everyone who is logged-in and their display.

Comment: Note that the argument to Xorg is (at least now, in 2016) optional and (at least on Fedora) usually absent, so this method no longer works at all.

Comment: If for some reason just setting the environment var won't always work... try prepending it to a command `DISPLAY=:0 netsurf "https://medium.com/"`... or using `export DISPLAY=:0` to share the var with the process, not just the shell

Answer (score 18):

```
# Show all active login shells, with displays
$ w -oush

trunc-us tty1                      23:02  -bash
trunc-us tty7     :0                4days /sbin/upstart --user
trunc-us pts/4    :0                      w -oush

# Capture the Display part
$ w -oush | grep -Eo ' :[0-9]+'

 :0
 :0

# only unique lines
$ w -oush | grep -Eo ' :[0-9]+' | uniq

 :0

# trim off the leading space
$ w -oush | grep -Eo ' :[0-9]+' | uniq | cut -d \  -f 2
```

[Edit: I ran an Xnest instance to see if this would catch it - it doesn't; it only captures login shells ('w' is short for 'who').  Back to the drawing board for me.]
[Edit: Found it:

```
$ ls /tmp/.X11-unix

X0 X2

$ ls /tmp/.X11-unix | tr 'X' ':'
:0
:2
```

]

Comment: That's... odd...  I wonder what the explanation there is.

Comment: (regarding GDM running on display 1024 for me ) I couldn't replicate it a second time. At the time I was trying out xrdp, windowed X11 forwarding and a few VNC clients. It seems that in a typical installation, GDM will run on X0... or X1 if you've hit the "log in as another user" button on the lock screen. Your second method worked for me on Fedora 23

Comment: I found something on Display 1024 using your command, but I see nothing running there... using `ps xeww | grep DISPLAY=:1024` now that's wierd. I'm running chrome-remote-desktop on display 20 aswell.

Comment: `w` does not work if no application is running on the x server (including no window manager and no desktop). But `ls /tmp/.X11-unix` does work.

Answer (score 10):

```
ps e | grep -Po " DISPLAY=[\.0-9A-Za-z:]* " | sort -u
```

will do the job by listing all current DISPLAYs. Also you can see the assigned displays for a specific user ($usr) with:

```
ps e -u $usr | grep -Po " DISPLAY=[\.0-9A-Za-z:]* " | sort -u
```

Comment: Is that second one meant to be `ps e -u $USER | grep -Po " DISPLAY=[\.0-9A-Za-z:]* " | sort -u` ?

Answer (score -1):

In the `/tmp` folder there can also be `.X??-lock` files with `??` indicating the session numbers.

You need to delete these if you want to re-use a session number.

You can see them using `ls -a` as normally files starting with a `.` are hidden.

Comment: Those are the display sessions?