# What are X server, display and screen?

Tags: x11, display, terminology

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17278/674

> If you run `ssh -X localhost`, you should see that `$DISPLAY` is
>   (probably) **`localhost:10.0`**. Contrast with **`:0.0`,** which is the value
>   when you're not connected over SSH. (The `.0` part may be omitted;
>   it's a screen number, but **multiple screens** are rarely used.) There are
>   two forms of X displays that you're likely to ever encounter:
>
> - Local displays, with nothing before the `:`.
> - TCP displays, with a hostname before the `:`.
>
> With `ssh -X localhost`, you can access **the X server** through **both
>   displays**, but the applications will use a different method: `:NUMBER`
>   accesses the server via local sockets and shared memory, whereas
>   `HOSTNAME:NUMBER` accesses the server over TCP, which is slower and
>   disables some extensions.

What are the relations and differences between X server, display and
    screen?

What does "the X server through both display" mean? Does a "display"
    means a display server, i.e. an X server, so two "displays" means
    two display servers, i.e. two X servers.

What does "multiple screens" mean? Does a "screen" mean a display
    monitor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I will give you a visual example to explain the basics of X11 and what is going on in the background:

[image: X11 connections example]
[source](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=X11_connections_example.xml#Uhttps%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Ffolfy%2Fshared%2Fmaster%2FX11_connections_example.xml)

In this example you have a local X11-server with two "screens" on your hostA. Usually there would be only one server with one screen (:0.0), which spans across all your monitors (makes multi-monitor applications way easier). hostB has two X servers, where the second one has no physical display (e.g. virtual framebuffer for VNC). hostC is a headless server without any monitors.

**terminal 1a, 2a, 5a, 6a**:
If you open a local terminal, and set the display to :0.0 (default) or :0.1, the drawing calls for your graphical programs will be sent to the local X server directly via the memory.

**terminal 1b, 5b**:
If you ssh onto some server, usually the display will be set automatically to the local X server, if there is one available. Otherwise, it will not be set at all (reason see terminal 3).

**terminal 2b, 6b**:
If you ssh onto a server, and enable X11-forwarding via the "-X" parameter, a tunnel is automatically created through the ssh-connection. In this case, TCP Port 6010 (6000+display#) on hostB is forwarding the traffic to Port 6000 (X server #0) on hostA. Usually the first 10 displays are reserved for "real" servers, therefore ssh remaps display #10 (next user connecting with ssh -X while you're logged in, would then get #11). There is no additional X server started, and permissions for X-server #0 on hostA are handled automatically by ssh.

**terminal 4**:
If you add a hostname (e.g. localhost) in front of the display/screen#, X11 will also communicate via TCP instead of the memory.

**terminal 3**:
You can also directly send X11 commands over the network, without setting up a ssh-tunnel first. The main problem here is, that your network/firewall/etc. needs to be configured to allow this (beware X11 is practically not encrypted), and permissions for the X server need to be granted manually (xhosts or Xauthority).

### To answer your questions

> What are the relations and differences between X server, display and screen?

A display just refers to *some* X server *somewhere*. The term "both displays" was referring to ":0.0" on the local computer ("local display") being equal to "localhost:10.0" on the ssh-target ("TCP display"). "screens" is referring the different virtual monitors (framebuffers) of the X server. "localhost:10.0" is only redirecting to the local X server, there is no X server started on the ssh-target (see scenario terminal 2b/6b).

Comment: Thanks. Did you create the diagram? Very impressive, an takes me a while to read. When I run `DISPLAY=192.168.1.198:0 eog`, it says 
`Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused`.  How shall I make it work? Do I need to make the X server on the remote host accept TCP connection?

Comment: If that IP is your remote Host's IP. It simply because your there's no x server listening on tcp:192.168.1.198:6000. @Tim If you want that to work, you have multiple solution, safe or not safe, simple or not simple.

Comment: Yes, I created the diagram (might use it for some future trainings). As written in the terminal 3 example (direct X11 connection across servers), theres two primary things to do: Your firewall needs to be opened (in your case allowing connections to tcp:192.168.1.198:6000, as  炸鱼薯条德里克 wrote), and you need to look up how to configure X11 permissions with e.g. xhosts.

This assumes that a working X server is running on 192.168.1.198, so `DISPLAY=192.168.1.198:0 eog` should work if executed locally on that server.

Comment: `"localhost:10.0" is only redirecting to the local X server, there is no X server started on the ssh-target.` What is the target terminal doing without a X11 server? Like how `:0` and `:1` refer to X-servers (and then `Monitor 1` and `VNC`), 2hat "display" does `localhost:10` refer to then? @Folfy

Comment: Please see drawing and description for terminal 2b and 6b. For X11-Forwarding to make sense, you're supposed to have an X11 Server already running on your ssh-client host, and that's where the X11 traffic is redirected/forwarded to.