# How can I find out the X servers (command, or pid) for display numbers?

Tags: x11, display

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17278/674

> Local displays correspond to a socket in `/tmp/.X11-unix`.
>
> ```
> (cd /tmp/.X11-unix && for x in X*; do echo ":${x#X}"; done)
> ```

On a computer:

```
$ (cd /tmp/.X11-unix && for x in X*; do echo ":${x#X}"; done)
:0
:1
:10
:11
:2
:3
:4
:5
:6
:7
:8
:9
```

I was wondering how to find out the X servers (command, or pid) for the given display numbers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lsof /tmp/.X11-unix/X*
```

as root will list the commands and pids corresponding to each socket. You can then match the socket name to the display number, as you’ve done in your example.

Comment: So you're not gonna tell me how to `grep` these results to get pid or command, huh?