# What are Xorg DISPLAY numbers?

Tags: xorg, display

Should I imagine it like a TCP/UDP port (per-machine rather than per-user)?
Can I connect to an other users DISPLAY? Is it protected somehow?

Can I list the currently used DISPLAY numbers for one user?
Is it possible to find one free DISPLAY number that I can still use?

Where could I find out more about these?

Comment: Related: [Is there a command to list all open displays on a machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/is-there-a-command-to-list-all-open-displays-on-a-machine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I imagine it like a TCP/UDP port (per-machine rather than per-user)?

It actually *is* a unix domain socket for local users, and a TCP port (if enabled, on modern X servers it's disabled by default).

> Can I connect to an other users DISPLAY?

Yes, with proper authorization. See `xauth` and `xhost`.

> Can I list the currently used DISPLAY numbers for one user?

Display numbers are per X server, and not per user.

> Is it possible to find one free DISPLAY number that I can still use?

`ps axu | grep Xorg` should list all X servers, you can see which display number they use. Or look at `/tmp/.X11-unix/` to see the unix domain sockets. Possibly there are variations for this among distros.

In general you should have an idea how many X servers are running on your system, if you have root rights and configured it ...