# How to run xrestop remotely?

Tags: xorg, x11, remote

I need to run `xrestop` on a remote machine. When I connect through `ssh` and run `xrestop` I get the results for my local machine.

I see that there is an option `-display` but I don't know how to use it.

How to run `xrestop` remotely ?

Comment: Maybe it's because of X11Forwarding. Can you try with **ForwardX11** set to **No** in _~/.ssh/config_ ?

Comment: See also [If you SSH into another computer, how to access other X displays?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26225) and [Open a window on a remote X display (why "Cannot open display")?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the `-display` option as normal.  The standard display is `:0`.  So if you're logged in via ssh you can run:

```
xrestop -display :0
```

Generally you can also explicitly set your `DISPLAY` shell variable to `:0` and all X programs will interact with the remote machines primary display.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted. I had tried with "-display :0.0" without success.