# How to make "notify-send" work from daemon application

Tags: gnome, init-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I launch a graphical program on another user's desktop as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root)

I wrote a script which starts from init.d .When it finishes I need it to notify-send a message to me (I am running GNOME). I tried

> export DISPLAY=:0.0

but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `notify-send` uses DBus, so you'll probably need to set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable as well.

Comment: Here is an example script calling notify-send from udev http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/

Comment: Another example is under the question [How to make notify-send work on /etc/init.d/a_script](http://superuser.com/a/837491/61370)