# Laptop keyboard occasionally stops working

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard

I have a dirty solution that is to plug a USB keyboard in and execute the following command:

```
setxkbmap -rules evdev -layout us -model evdev
```

Afterward my keyboard will work.

This solution only works if I have a usb keyboard handy which is seldom the case and I am forced to reboot my laptop. I have tried to have the command auto execute when the system wakes by adding:

```
set -e

if [ "${1}" = "resume" ] && [ "${2}" != "standby" ]; then
        setxkbmap -rules evdev -layout us -model evdev
fi
exit 0
```

to: /etc/apm/event.d/enable_xkb
But this does not work. I am guessing because it is not run by the appropriate user.

So there are two possible answers to this question:
1) How do I get the above script to execute after my system wakes up. If I can get this to work I can simply put my computer to sleep and wake it back up and have the keyboard working again.
2) (preferred) How do I actually fix this probelem.

More details about situation that my be needed to answer 2)
Due to the randomness of this problem I do not know when this issue first started. I do know that it exists on Debian Unstable, and Testing but not Stable. It also exists on curret Arch linux but not before November 2012. My system is a Lenovo w520.

Also note: This is a bit of a heisenbug, as such I would not be able to accept a response until it has worked for a few days.

Further clarification:
When this happens I am unable to switch to any of the tty#s so no console does not work. I have also tried the "Raising Skinny Elephants is Utterly Boring" combo and this does not work either... After I post I will check if this works when my keyboard is functional. It is very random, sometimes it will be fine for a couple days and bam my keyboard doesn't work.

Comment: CRON-job it, bro. Simply `export DISPLAY=:0` and run your command above. Run it once every second if you'd like, or even once every 15 to 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your script doesn't work from the resume hook is that it doesn't know which X server to talk to. You need to set the `DISPLAY` environment variable, and perhaps `XAUTHORITY` as well. See [Can I launch a graphical program on another user's desktop as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root/1600#1600) for more explanations.

Here's a shell snippet that runs the desired command on all active displays.

```
if [ "${1}" = "resume" ] && [ "${2}" != "standby" ]; then
  for p in $(ps -C Xorg -o pid=); do
    </proc/$p/cmdline awk -v RS='\0' '/^:[0-9]$/ {print} $0=="-auth" {getline; print}' | {
        read DISPLAY; export DISPLAY
        read XAUTHORITY && export XAUTHORITY || unset XAUTHORITY
        setxkbmap -rules evdev -layout us -model evdev
     }
  done
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope this works... I actually haven't had the issue in a couple days since I updated to the latest kernel. But it wouldn't be the first time the problem came back after a few days. If it happens again and this works I will accept. If it doesn't happen in about a week, I will accept on faith :).

Comment: Well, it seems it didn't work... The issue happened again and I couldn't recover the keyboard.... It may be that your script is correct but /etc/apm/event.d/enable_xkb isn't being called when I close the lid. I will look into it some more.

Comment: I now have a solution that definitely calls the script upon resuming... So it appears I was reading some stale documentation for my original hook.

Comment: Well the above script is being executed each time I resume but it doesn't fix the issue. I know if I plug a usb keyboard and execute 
    setxkbmap -rules evdev -layout us -model evdev
It will fix the issue.