# X Forwarding over SSH when switching users

Tags: ssh, x11, su

How do I forward X when switching users?

I can `ssh -X username@server.example.com` and open GUIs just fine. However, then when I `sudo su` to root, the X11 forwarding seems to stop because the windows never seem to launch.

ssh access is disabled for root, otherwise I would just connect directly.

Comment: if ssh for root is disabled then how can you use x11 forwarding for root?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set up the magic cookies and the `DISPLAY` environment variable appropriately. While the latter is done easily, the latter is a bit more complicated. In some cases using insecure forwarding `ssh -Y` might be a solution, but I generally advise against the X11 over SSH. In most cases it is better to use [VNC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80690/22886).