# Display a Server Desktop To Remote User

Tags: ssh, x11, xorg, x-server, remote-desktop

I installed Ubuntu desktop to my AWS server, and it boots successfully. I know this because AWS lets me take an instance screenshot, and it shows the log-in screen of the desktop. The only problem is, is when I log on via PuTty- with X11 enabled, I still get the terminal. I know for a fact the desktop is there- is it that X11 doesn't support transferring those graphics to my Xserver? If so, what can I do?

I am using Windows VcXsrv

Comment: Do you want the local desktop session from the machine, or a newly spawned session, independent of the local session? Do you want to set this up for multiple users? X11/RDP/VNC? Are you running Wayland or X11 on the server? There are several ways to skin this cat. This Q needs more focus and details. Read into these a bit for more terminology: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80683/remote-desktop-kde-over-ssh-reverse-tunnel  and https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do what you are describing is to install [x2goserver](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) on the AWS end and use x2goclient on your to connect in from your Windows box

Comment: Thanks! Turns out X11 tunneling doesn't support this.