# Setting DISPLAY in systemd service file

Tags: opensuse, systemd

I'm trying to learn systemd services by trying to start xclock as a service; the service file is below

```
[Unit]
Description=clock

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xclock

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Any ideas what's wrong here? I'm getting an error saying "cannot connect to display."

Answer (score 26, accepted):

An application needs two things to open a window on an X display. It needs to know the location of the X display; that's conveyed by the `DISPLAY` environment variable. It also needs to authenticate with the X server. This is conveyed through a cookie, which is a secret value generated by the X server when it starts and stored in a file that only the user who started the X server can access. The default cookie file is `~/.Xauthority`.

If your X server is using the default cookie file location, then adding `Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/dogs/.Xauthority` will work (assuming `/home/dogs` is the home directory of the user who is logged in under X). If you need to find the location, see [Can I launch a graphical program on another user's desktop as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root/1600#1600) and [Open a window on a remote X display (why “Cannot open display”)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126)

Alternatively, running the program as the user who is running the X server will work, provided that the cookie file is in the default location (if not, you'll have to locate the cookie file, like in the root case). Add the `User` directive (e.g. `User=dogs`).

Of course the service won't run if there isn't an X display by that number owned by the user you specify.

It's rather bizarre to start a GUI program from Systemd. It wasn't designed for this. GUI programs live in an X session, started by a user. Systemd is for system processes. You should experiment with daemons instead.

Comment: It's not a problem using `systemctl --user`. Also the `DISPLAY` variable is not a matter then. Have a  look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519585/105615).

Comment: Having the same issue, where I'm trying to auto-magically boot into X with a Chromium configured in `--kiosk` mode. We are building a Kiosk-like product which should always boot up into full screen mode with the web app fully loaded. I've seen cases where it works perfect and other times it had issues (like a race condition of some sort).

Comment: This might also help if there is no graphical-session.target: https://superuser.com/a/1128905/683326

Comment: On newer versions of Ubuntu/GDM, the Xauthority file is found here: `/run/user/<uid>/gdm/Xauthority`.

Comment: can't find Xauthority in linux mendel os

Comment: @BhanuchanderUdhayakumar Gdm likes to put it in different places. Check `echo $XAUTHORITY`. If that doesn't help, ask a new question. I know nothing about mendel os.

Answer (score 3):

A modern way (in 2021) is not to hard code the environment within the `.service` unit file. Instead, do something like this:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh
#!/bin/sh

systemctl --user import-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY

if command -v dbus-update-activation-environment >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    dbus-update-activation-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
fi
```

This is what is done in Arch Linux, for example.

Explanation: When starting X11, both the `DISPLAY` and the `XAUTHORITY` environment variables are inherited for *all* systemd user service unit files (i.e. those managed by `systemd --user`).

One could check those are properly set by running `systemctl --user show-environment`.

By doing so, you don't need to use `Environment=` directives in your `.service` files.

Comment: where should this file be linked in the ```custom.service``` file

Answer (score -2):

You can add in `.xinitrc` :

```
xhost si:localuser:$USER
```

It works for me!

Comment: this is for systemd service files, not .xinitrc