# systemctl to start cron-like job

Tags: cron, systemd

In `/etc/systemd/system` directory I have:

`rsnapshot-backup.service` file, with following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=rsnapshot backup automation [cron like]

[Service]
Nice=19
IOSchedulingClass=2
IOSchedulingPriority=7
ExecStart=/usr/bin/notify-send "Rsnapshot Hourly Backup In Progress"
```

and `rsnapshot-backup.timer` file, with following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=hourly rsnapshot backup

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:43:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

But I don't see `notify-send` being triggered? What might be wrong?

`systemctl list-timers` gives:

```
NEXT                          LEFT          LAST           PASSED                  UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Sat 2014-08-16 09:43:00 CEST  2min 37s left Sat 2014-08-16 09:31:18 CEST  9min ago rsnapshot-backup.timer       rsnapshot-backup.service
```

`systemctl status rsnapshot-backup.service` gives:

```
● rsnapshot-backup.service - rsnapshot backup automation [cron like]
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rsnapshot-backup.service; static)
    Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2014-08-16 09:31:21 CEST; 11min ago
    Process: 228 ExecStart=/usr/bin/notify-send Rsnapshot Hourly Backup In Progress (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Main PID: 228 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

`systemctl status rsnapshot-backup.timer` gives:

```
● rsnapshot-backup.timer - hourly rsnapshot backup
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rsnapshot-backup.timer; enabled)
    Active: active (waiting) since Sat 2014-08-16 09:31:16 CEST; 12min ago
```

**EDIT**
Doing `journalctl -u rsnapshot-backup`, I can confirm that the service was
successfuly started, however nothing seen on display (notify-send)..

```
-- Reboot --
Aug 16 09:43:14 ----------------- systemd[1]: Starting rsnapshot backup automation [cron like]...
Aug 16 09:43:14 ----------------- systemd[1]: Started rsnapshot backup automation [cron like].
Aug 16 10:00:06 ----------------- systemd[1]: Starting rsnapshot backup automation [cron like]...
Aug 16 10:00:07 ----------------- systemd[1]: Started rsnapshot backup automation [cron like].
Aug 16 10:19:04 ----------------- systemd[1]: Starting rsnapshot backup automation [cron like]...
Aug 16 10:19:04 ----------------- systemd[1]: Started rsnapshot backup automation [cron like].
```

Comment: You'll need to specify `Environment=DISPLAY=:0` for `notify-send` to run on...

Comment: How and where would I need to specify that? Do you mean by adding that line, above `ExecStart`?

Comment: Yes. See `man systemd.service` for the details...

Comment: Yes I read it, even tried `/bin/sh -c 'notify-send "msg"'`, without any success, see my edits for a journalctl log.

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85244/setting-display-in-systemd-service-file

Comment: After adding one more line: `User=myusername` it works. It has to be username of the user who started the X server. Thanks for pointing me in right direction, by giving that link.